# In what cases do I use malloc and/or new?

Tags: c++, memory-management, malloc, new-operator

I see in C++ there are multiple ways to allocate and free data and I understand that when you call `malloc` you should call `free` and when you use the `new` operator you should pair with `delete` and it is a mistake to mix the two (e.g. Calling `free()` on something that was created with the `new` operator), but I'm not clear on when I should use `malloc`/ `free` and when I should use `new`/ `delete` in my real world programs.

If you're a C++ expert, please let me know any rules of thumb or conventions you follow in this regard.

Comment: I'd just like to add a reminder that you cannot mix the two styles - that is, you cannot use new to create an object and then call free() on it, nor attempt to delete a block allocated by malloc(). Probably obvious to say it, but nonetheless...

Comment: Good answers, all I have to add (that I haven't seen) is that new/delete calls the constructor/destructor for you, malloc/free does not. Just a difference worth mentioning.

Comment: With modern C++, I'm still trying to find a reason to use either.

Comment: Or use neither and go with std:shared_ptr<T>.  Then you don't have to delete at all.

Comment: std::unique_ptr<T> should be the default choice instead of std::shared_ptr<T>.

Answer (score 489):

Unless you are forced to use C, you should **never use** `malloc`.  Always use `new`.

If you need a big chunk of data just do something like:

```
char *pBuffer = new char[1024];
```

Be careful though this is not correct:

```
//This is incorrect - may delete only one element, may corrupt the heap, or worse...
delete pBuffer;
```

Instead you should do this when deleting an array of data:

```
//This deletes all items in the array
delete[] pBuffer;
```

The `new` keyword is the C++ way of doing it, and it will ensure that your type will have its **constructor called**.  The `new` keyword is also more **type-safe** whereas `malloc` is not type-safe at all.

The only way I could think that would be beneficial to use `malloc` would be if you needed to **change the size of your buffer** of data.  The `new` keyword does not have an analogous way like `realloc`.  The `realloc` function might be able to extend the size of a chunk of memory for you more efficiently.

It is worth mentioning that you cannot mix `new`/`free` and `malloc`/`delete`.

Note: Some answers in this question are invalid.

```
int* p_scalar = new int(5);  // Does not create 5 elements, but initializes to 5
int* p_array  = new int[5];  // Creates 5 elements
```

Comment: With regard to calling delete foo when you should call delete []foo, some compilers will fix this automagically for you and not leak and other will only delete the first entry and leak. I had a few of these in some code and valgrind will find them for you.

Comment: I verified this many years ago on VC++ with an array of objects and putting a breakpoint in my destructor.  Only the first one got deleted.  But ya, good point on some compilers catching this for you.

Comment: I don't think there's any memory leak if you don't use the [] syntax. But, only the destructor for the first array item will be called.

Comment: If your compiler doesn't auto convert your delete to delete[] then there is definitely a memory leak.

Comment: If you do not use the correct delete **the result is undefined**. It's incorrect. The fact that it might get part of the thing right or work sometimes is just blind luck.

Comment: I don't think it will cause heap corruption, it will just see it as an pointer to a single element.

Comment: See items 16.12, 16.14, and 38.7 in the C++ FAQ: 

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html#faq-16.12 

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/compiler-dependencies.html#faq-38.7

Comment: @KPexEA: Even if some compilers might fix your mistakes, it's still wrong to make them in the first place :) Always use delete[] where appropriate.

Comment: "Unless you are forced to use C, you should never use malloc. Always use new."

Why?  What is the win here?  For objects we need construction, but for memory blocks, you clearly document two ways to make coding mistakes (the more easily caught () vs [] in new and the less easily caught mismatched array vs scaler new and delete).  What is the motivation for using new/delete for blocks of raw memory?

Comment: type safe means? Can anyone please elaborate?

Comment: "type safety is the extent to which a programming language discourages or prevents type errors" - wikipedia first line

Comment: Do not ever, ever use `new[]` and `delete[]`, always use a `std::vector`.

Comment: @DeadMG: If one is creating an array for use by an asynchronous API function, wouldn't `new[]` be much safer than `std::vector`?  If one uses `new[]`, the only way the pointer would become invalid would be via explicit `delete`, whereas the memory allocated for an `std::vector` could invalidated when the vector is resized or leaves scope.  (Note that when using `new[]` one would have to allow for the possibility that one may not be able to call `delete` if the async method is still pending; if it may be necessary to abandon an async operation, one may have to arrange for delete via callback).

Comment: What about in the multithreading context with OpenMP for example? Are they equally thread safe?

Comment: What about  `realloc()`?, there is no `renew`

Comment: Actually never use the `new` but prefer it before `malloc` if you really have to use one of them. They both require a manual memory management done by you. Under (almost) all circumstances you have `std::vector` and smart pointers which free the memory when they are destructed.

Comment: `realloc` is a poor reason to prefer `malloc` considering almost everyone calls `realloc` incorrectly.

Comment: another poor reason is calloc

Comment: @immibis This is not sufficient? "it will ensure that your type will have their constructor called [...] is also more type safe whereas malloc is not typesafe at all."

Comment: Why malloc is not type safe?

Comment: @PaulCoccoli and the alternative `realloc` for `new` initialized quantities is ?

Comment: @Carpetfizz It depends on what those `new` initialized quantities are.  As stated multiple times above, there is no `new`-like version of realloc.

Comment: Would this: `int* i = new int{ 5 };` be a better way of initializing it than using round brackets?

Comment: @scottxiao you can do `int *array = (int *)malloc(15);//oops, last int would be corrupted` but you won't make this mistake with `new`.

Answer (score 169):

The short answer is: don't use `malloc` for C++ without a really good reason for doing so. `malloc` has a number of deficiencies when used with C++, which `new` was defined to overcome.

### Deficiencies fixed by new for C++ code

1. `malloc` is not typesafe in any meaningful way. In C++ you are required to cast the return from `void*`. This potentially introduces a lot of problems:

   ```
   #include <stdlib.h>

   struct foo {
     double d[5];
   }; 

   int main() {
     foo *f1 = malloc(1); // error, no cast
     foo *f2 = static_cast<foo*>(malloc(sizeof(foo)));
     foo *f3 = static_cast<foo*>(malloc(1)); // No error, bad
   }
   ```
2. It's worse than that though. If the type in question is [POD (plain old data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c) then you can semi-sensibly use `malloc` to allocate memory for it, as `f2` does in the first example.

   It's not so obvious though if a type is POD. The fact that it's possible for a given type to change from POD to non-POD with no resulting compiler error and potentially very hard to debug problems is a significant factor. For example if someone (possibly another programmer, during maintenance, much later on were to make a change that caused `foo` to no longer be POD then no obvious error would appear at compile time as you'd hope, e.g.:

   ```
   struct foo {
     double d[5];
     virtual ~foo() { }
   };
   ```

   would make the `malloc` of `f2` also become bad, without any obvious diagnostics. The   example here is trivial, but it's possible to accidentally introduce non-PODness much further away (e.g. in a base class, by adding a non-POD member). If you have C++11/boost you can use `is_pod` to check that this assumption is correct and produce an error if it's not:

   ```
   #include <type_traits>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   foo *safe_foo_malloc() {
     static_assert(std::is_pod<foo>::value, "foo must be POD");
     return static_cast<foo*>(malloc(sizeof(foo)));
   }
   ```

   Although boost is [unable to determine if a type is POD](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_pod.html) without C++11 or some other compiler extensions.
3. `malloc` returns `NULL` if allocation fails. `new` will throw `std::bad_alloc`. The behaviour of later using a `NULL` pointer is undefined. An exception has clean semantics when it is thrown and it is thrown from the source of the error. Wrapping `malloc` with an appropriate test at every call seems tedious and error prone. (You only have to forget once to undo all that good work). An exception can be allowed to propagate to a level where a caller is able to sensibly process it, where as `NULL` is much harder to pass back meaningfully. We could extend our `safe_foo_malloc` function to throw an exception or exit the program or call some handler:

   ```
   #include <type_traits>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   void my_malloc_failed_handler();

   foo *safe_foo_malloc() {
     static_assert(std::is_pod<foo>::value, "foo must be POD");
     foo *mem = static_cast<foo*>(malloc(sizeof(foo)));
     if (!mem) {
        my_malloc_failed_handler();
        // or throw ...
     }
     return mem;
   }
   ```
4. Fundamentally `malloc` is a C feature and `new` is a C++ feature. As a result `malloc` does not play nicely with constructors, it only looks at allocating a chunk of bytes. We could extend our `safe_foo_malloc` further to use placement `new`:

   ```
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <new>

   void my_malloc_failed_handler();

   foo *safe_foo_malloc() {
     void *mem = malloc(sizeof(foo));
     if (!mem) {
        my_malloc_failed_handler();
        // or throw ...
     }
     return new (mem)foo();
   }
   ```
5. Our `safe_foo_malloc` function isn't very generic - ideally we'd want something that can handle any type, not just `foo`. We can achieve this with templates and variadic templates for non-default constructors:

   ```
   #include <functional>
   #include <new>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   void my_malloc_failed_handler();

   template <typename T>
   struct alloc {
     template <typename ...Args>
     static T *safe_malloc(Args&&... args) {
       void *mem = malloc(sizeof(T));
       if (!mem) {
          my_malloc_failed_handler();
          // or throw ...
       }
       return new (mem)T(std::forward(args)...);
     }
   };
   ```

   Now though in fixing all the issues we identified so far we've practically reinvented the default `new` operator. If you're going to use `malloc` and placement `new` then you might as well just use `new` to begin with!

Comment: It's too bad C++ made `struct` and `class` mean basically the same thing; I wonder if there would have been any problems with having `struct` be reserved for PODs and possibly having all `class` types be presumed to be non-PODs.  Any types defined by code which predated the invention of C++ would necessarily be PODs, so I wouldn't think backward compatibility would be an issue there.  Are there advantages to having non-PODs types declared as `struct` rather than `class`?

Comment: @supercat A bit late but as it turns out, making `struct` and `class` do almost the same thing was a wonderful design decision that now enables a neat feature called ["metaclasses" (from Herb)](https://herbsutter.com/2017/07/26/metaclasses-thoughts-on-generative-c/).

Comment: @Rakete1111: At first glance, that proposal looks like it preprocesses a version of the language that uses dollar-prefixed keywords like `$class`.  I'm not sure what that has to do with `class` and `struct` being synonyms, however.

Comment: @supercat The type system would have been bifurcated more. By having `class` and `struct` mean effectively the same thing, you can do arbitrary transformations on them (`$class`) without worrying of making a `class` a `struct` and vice-versa.

Comment: @Rakete1111: If certain kinds of operations and transformations are safe with some types but not others, having the type directly identify that, and having a compiler reject unsafe operations and transformations, would seem better than having a change to a metaclass which was used in ways that are only suitable for a PODS, get silently changed to a non-PODS.

Comment: @supercat I think I wasn't clear, sorry. What I meant was something akin to `template<class T> struct X { T t; };` only being valid for when T is a pod. The same can apply to metaclasses, when do you a transformation on the class that might change it's member in a way that makes the class a pod; either accidentally or not.

Comment: @Rakete1111: The requirements for something to be a PODS are a bit stricter than the requirements for presence within a `struct` should be; the biggest requirement should be standard layout. The notion of a `struct` in C was tied to the notion that each `T` occupies a range of `sizeof (T)` consecutive bytes, and a struct is the concatenation of such byte sequences with optional padding, while the notion of "size" is meaningless for class types.

Answer (score 59):

From the [C++ FQA Lite](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/heap.html#fqa-16.4):

> [16.4] Why should I use new instead of
>   trustworthy old malloc()?
>
> FAQ: new/delete call the
>   constructor/destructor; new is type
>   safe, malloc is not; new can be
>   overridden by a class.
>
> FQA: The virtues of new mentioned by
>   the FAQ are not virtues, because
>   constructors, destructors, and
>   operator overloading are garbage (see
>   what happens when you have no garbage
>   collection?), and the type safety
>   issue is really tiny here (normally
>   you have to cast the void* returned by
>   malloc to the right pointer type to
>   assign it to a typed pointer variable,
>   which may be annoying, but far from
>   "unsafe").
>
> Oh, and using trustworthy old malloc
>   makes it possible to use the equally
>   trustworthy & old realloc. Too bad we
>   don't have a shiny new operator renew or something.
>
> Still, new is not bad enough to
>   justify a deviation from the common
>   style used throughout a language, even
>   when the language is C++. In
>   particular, classes with non-trivial
>   constructors will misbehave in fatal
>   ways if you simply malloc the objects.
>   So why not use new throughout the
>   code? People rarely overload operator
>   new, so it probably won't get in your
>   way too much. And if they do overload
>   new, you can always ask them to stop.

Sorry, I just couldn't resist. :)

Comment: I cannot take this comment serious as it clearly projects the author's biased against C++. C++ is a language used to create performance oriented software, and a garbage collector could only be detrimental to its objective. I disagree with your entire answer!

Comment: @Miguel You missed the joke.

Answer (score 55):

Always use new in C++. If you need a block of untyped memory, you can use operator new directly:

```
void *p = operator new(size);
   ...
operator delete(p);
```

Comment: interesting, i always just allocated an array of unsigned char when i need a raw data buffer like this.

Comment: @Greg - either way works the same. I just like the fact than calling operator new emphasizes that I'm doing a low-level untyped allocation.

Comment: The opposite of `operator new` is `operator delete`. It is not a well defined action to call `delete` on an expression with type `void*`.

Answer (score 52):

**new vs malloc()**

1) `new` is an **operator**, while `malloc()` is a **function**.

2) `new` calls **constructors**, while `malloc()` does not.

3) `new` returns **exact data type**, while `malloc()` returns **void ***.

4) `new` never returns a **NULL** (will throw on failure) while `malloc()` returns NULL

5) Reallocation of memory not handled by `new` while `malloc()` can

Comment: Hi , For point 4) , new can be instructed to return NULL on failure.                  `char* ptr = new (std::nothrow) char [323232];`

Comment: 6) new creates from constructor arguments, while malloc uses size.

Comment: there is also a `new` function

Comment: If you were so inclined in C as to *reallocate*, I would hope that you'd use `realloc` rather than `malloc`, and start off with your pointer variable initialised to `NULL`. If you want a *resizable* chunk of memory in C++, on the other hand, I would be suggesting `std::vector` as opposed to `realloc`... That or a file.

Answer (score 35):

To answer your question, you should know **the difference between `malloc` and `new`**. The difference is simple:

`malloc` **allocates memory**, while `new` **allocates memory AND calls the constructor** of the object you're allocating memory for.

So, unless you're restricted to C, you should never use malloc, especially when dealing with C++ objects. That would be a recipe for breaking your program.

Also the difference between `free` and `delete` is quite the same. The difference is that `delete` will call the destructor of your object in addition to freeing memory.

Answer (score 34):

Use **`malloc`** and **`free`** *only* for allocating memory that is going to be managed by c-centric libraries and APIs. Use **`new`** and **`delete`** (and the **`[]`** variants) for everything that you control.

Comment: Also notice that well written C library will hide malloc and free internally, this is how the C programmer should work.

Comment: @dmckee do you have an example of C++ using c-centric libraries by malloc and free?

Comment: @Dacav: If a C function will accept a pointer to an object that it will need to keep using after the function returns, and the caller will have no way of knowing when the object is still needed, it would be perfectly reasonable for the function to specify that the pointer must have been created with `malloc`.  Likewise if a function like `strdup` needs to create an object and return it to a caller, it is perfectly reasonable to specify that the caller must call `free` on the object when it is no longer needed.  How could such functions avoid exposing their use of malloc/free to the caller?

Comment: @supercat, there's something inherently wrong in having a C function accept a pointer to objects, since C is not aware of objects at all.

In general I believe the best approach is having semantic wrappers around allocation/deallocation also in C. It can be still acceptable, but less flexible, if a C library is asking the caller to pre-allocate and/or deallocate memory. If a C function is doing this and claiming ownership on the allocated memory, you are implicitly required to allocate it with malloc.

Comment: @supercat One example of an every-day package which I'm sure everyone has used is libgmp. If you've ever used any open-source encryption or software based on such encryption (which is very likely) then you've probably used an arbitrary precision arithmetic library which needs to grow and shrink its own internal data. This is done using an initialisation function... and then you gotta wonder, how do you use the C code which is libgmp, in C++, without recompiling it in C++? Now with that (the linker) in mind, think about it... why would any sensible person *ever* put `malloc` in C++?

Comment: @Sebivor: The C Standard overloads the term "object" for a number of  different but related concepts which differ from how it's used in other contexts.

Comment: I think that Dacav is suggesting that c libraries implementing opaque types ought to offer a facility for initializing the opaque storage so that the details of who those objects are managed internally are completely hidden and the caller doesn't even have to know what memory management scheme is used internally. But however you feel about that prescription, there are many places where the caller is expected to do the allocation (starting with unix `FILE`s).

Comment: Sebivor: I think, though, perhaps you meant your comment for @Decav?

Comment: [I meant @Dacav]

Comment: @dmckee: It was Dacav that said that C is not aware of objects at all.  Neither the C core language nor the Standard Library has a broad-reaching concept of functions that create persistent storage or entities as part of their operation, other than those whose purpose is to create such entities (e.g. malloc, fopen, etc.); all other functions that operate on such entities expect them to have been created by their caller, either by using functions whose sole purpose was such creation, or by such means as the caller sees fit.

Comment: @Sebivor: The C Standard overloads the term to describe variables, struct members, union members, array elements, malloc-allocated regions, and pointer targets, which leads to problems in places like e.g. 6.5p7 which limits the cases where an "object" can have its stored value accessed.

Comment: @supercat I assume the C++ standard inherits the C standards definition, since it doesn't otherwise seem to have one, and for every C++ compiler I've ever used there's been a compatible C ABI, which includes things like structure layout and internal representation of types. Additionally, the C++ standard actually talks about basic types like arrays of characters as though *they* are objects.

Comment: Wait, no, C++ **does** have a definition for "object". It says it plain and clear... "An object is a region of storage."

Comment: @Dacav From the C++ standard, the section entited [The C++ object model](http://cpp14.centaur.ath.cx/intro.object.html), we can see a definition for *object*: *"An object is a region of storage."* There's a similar definition in the C standard; `char c;` in both C and C++, this variable denotes an object. The difference is that *some* (but not all) objects in C++ are *also* polymorphic (because C++ is OO, after all). Don't make the mistake of believing only object oriented code can use objects.

Comment: @Sebivor, these messages are quite old, is this comment thread still alive? At any rate, I'm using object-oriented design for C programs as well, so I totally agree with you

Comment: @Dacav Really? If you design a function which requires a specific form of allocation (and forces the rest of the world to use that allocation when called upon), that's technically a violation of dependency inversion principle, one of the five core principles of object oriented design. Not everything you can do in C++ is object oriented, and there isn't a whole lot you can do with pure object oriented constructs. You can't compose logic (sequence, selection and iteration) without (typically) procedural or functional constructs. OO is just a more specific form of one of those with extensions.

Answer (score 16):

There is one big difference between `malloc` and `new`. `malloc` allocates memory. This is fine for C, because in C, a lump of memory is an object.

In C++, if you're not dealing with POD types (which are similar to C types) you must call a constructor on a memory location to actually have an object there. Non-POD types are very common in C++, as many C++ features make an object automatically non-POD.

`new` allocates memory *and* creates an object on that memory location. For non-POD types this means calling a constructor.

If you do something like this:

```
non_pod_type* p = (non_pod_type*) malloc(sizeof *p);
```

The pointer you obtain cannot be dereferenced because it does not point to an object. You'd need to call a constructor on it before you can use it (and this is done using placement `new`).

If, on the other hand, you do:

```
non_pod_type* p = new non_pod_type();
```

You get a pointer that is always valid, because `new` created an object.

Even for POD types, there's a significant difference between the two:

```
pod_type* p = (pod_type*) malloc(sizeof *p);
std::cout << p->foo;
```

This piece of code would print an unspecified value, because the POD objects created by `malloc` are not initialised.

With `new`, you could specify a constructor to call, and thus get a well defined value.

```
pod_type* p = new pod_type();
std::cout << p->foo; // prints 0
```

If you really want it, you can use use `new` to obtain uninitialised POD objects. See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new/620402#620402) for more information on that.

Another difference is the behaviour upon failure. When it fails to allocate memory, `malloc` returns a null pointer, while `new` throws an exception.

The former requires you to test every pointer returned before using it, while the later will always produce valid pointers.

For these reasons, in C++ code you should use `new`, and not `malloc`. But even then, you should not use `new` "in the open", because it acquires resources you need to release later on. When you use `new` you should pass its result immediately into a resource managing class:

```
std::unique_ptr<T> p = std::unique_ptr<T>(new T()); // this won't leak
```

Answer (score 16):

Dynamic allocation is only required when the life-time of the object should be different than the scope it gets created in (This holds as well for making the scope smaller as larger) and you have a specific reason where storing it by value doesn't work.

For example:

```
 std::vector<int> *createVector(); // Bad
 std::vector<int> createVector();  // Good

 auto v = new std::vector<int>(); // Bad
 auto result = calculate(/*optional output = */ v);
 auto v = std::vector<int>(); // Good
 auto result = calculate(/*optional output = */ &v);
```

From C++11 on, we have `std::unique_ptr` for dealing with allocated memory, which contains the ownership of the allocated memory. `std::shared_ptr` was created for when you have to share ownership. (you'll need this less than you would expect in a good program)

Creating an instance becomes really easy:

```
auto instance = std::make_unique<Class>(/*args*/); // C++14
auto instance = std::unique_ptr<Class>(new Class(/*args*/)); // C++11
auto instance = std::make_unique<Class[]>(42); // C++14
auto instance = std::unique_ptr<Class[]>(new Class[](42)); // C++11
```

C++17 also adds `std::optional` which can prevent you from requiring memory allocations

```
auto optInstance = std::optional<Class>{};
if (condition)
    optInstance = Class{};
```

As soon as 'instance' goes out of scope, the memory gets cleaned up. Transferring ownership is also easy:

```
 auto vector = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Interface>>{};
 auto instance = std::make_unique<Class>();
 vector.push_back(std::move(instance)); // std::move -> transfer (most of the time)
```

So when do you still need `new`? Almost never from C++11 on. Most of the you use `std::make_unique` until you get to a point where you hit an API that transfers ownership via raw pointers.

```
 auto instance = std::make_unique<Class>();
 legacyFunction(instance.release()); // Ownership being transferred

 auto instance = std::unique_ptr<Class>{legacyFunction()}; // Ownership being captured in unique_ptr
```

In C++98/03, you have to do manual memory management. If you are in this case, try upgrading to a more recent version of the standard. If you are stuck:

```
 auto instance = new Class(); // Allocate memory
 delete instance;             // Deallocate
 auto instances = new Class[42](); // Allocate memory
 delete[] instances;               // Deallocate
```

Make sure that you track the ownership correctly to not have any memory leaks! Move semantics don't work yet either.

So, when do we need malloc in C++? The only valid reason would be to allocate memory and initialize it later via placement new.

```
 auto instanceBlob = std::malloc(sizeof(Class)); // Allocate memory
 auto instance = new(instanceBlob)Class{}; // Initialize via constructor
 instance.~Class(); // Destroy via destructor
 std::free(instanceBlob); // Deallocate the memory
```

Even though, the above is valid, this can be done via a new-operator as well. `std::vector` is a good example for this.

Finally, we still have the elephant in the room: `C`. If you have to work with a C-library where memory gets allocated in the C++ code and freed in the C code (or the other way around), you are forced to use malloc/free.

If you are in this case, forget about virtual functions, member functions, classes ... Only structs with PODs in it are allowed.

Some exceptions to the rules:

- You are writing a standard library with advanced data structures where malloc is appropriate
- You have to allocate big amounts of memory (In memory copy of a 10GB file?)
- You have tooling preventing you to use certain constructs
- You need to store an incomplete type

Comment: Definite +1! New/delete and malloc/free are for our grandparents. Those are not the suggested means of performing dynamic allocation in modern C++. Objects and containers on the stack, unique_ptr, and shared_ptr are the "proper" ways to handle objects. I have example projects with 100,000's of lines of code with NO `malloc` or `new` calls.

Answer (score 7):

There are a few things which `new` does that `malloc` doesn’t:

1. `new` constructs the object by calling the constructor of that object
2. `new` doesn’t require typecasting of allocated memory.
3. It doesn’t require an amount of memory to be allocated, rather it requires a number of 
   objects to be constructed.

So, if you use `malloc`, then you need to do above things explicitly, which is not always practical. Additionally, `new` can be overloaded but `malloc` can’t be.

Answer (score 6):

If you work with data that doesn't need construction/destruction and requires reallocations (e.g., a large array of ints), then I believe malloc/free is a good choice as it gives you realloc, which is way faster than new-memcpy-delete (it is on my Linux box, but I guess this may be platform dependent). If you work with C++ objects that are not POD and require construction/destruction, then you must use the new and delete operators.

Anyway, I don't see why you shouldn't use both (provided that you free your malloced memory and delete objects allocated with new) if can take advantage of the speed boost (sometimes a significant one, if you're reallocing large arrays of POD) that realloc can give you.

Unless you need it though, you should stick to new/delete in C++.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using C++, try to use new/delete instead of malloc/calloc as they are operators. For malloc/calloc, you need to include another header. Don't mix two different languages in the same code. Their work is similar in every manner, both allocates memory dynamically from heap segment in hash table.

Answer (score 4):

`new` will initialise the default values of the struct and correctly links the references in it to itself.

E.g.

```
struct test_s {
    int some_strange_name = 1;
    int &easy = some_strange_name;
}
```

So `new struct test_s` will return an initialised structure with a working reference, while the malloc'ed version has no default values and the intern references aren't initialised.

Answer (score 3):

If you have C code you want to port over to C++, you might leave any malloc() calls in it.  For any new C++ code, I'd recommend using new instead.

Answer (score 3):

From a lower perspective, new will initialize all the memory before giving the memory whereas malloc will keep the original content of the memory.

Comment: new does not in general initialize memory, although there are ways to make that happen: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204176/how-to-initialise-memory-with-new-operator-in-c for one discussion about it.

Answer (score 2):

In the following scenario, we can't use new since it calls constructor.

```
class  B  {
private:
    B *ptr;
    int x;
public:
    B(int n)  {
        cout<<"B: ctr"<<endl;
        //ptr = new B;  //keep calling ctr, result is segmentation fault
        ptr = (B *)malloc(sizeof(B));
        x = n;
        ptr->x = n + 10;
    }
    ~B()  {
        //delete ptr;
        free(ptr);
        cout<<"B: dtr"<<endl;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Rare case to consider using malloc/free instead of new/delete is when you're allocating and then reallocating (simple pod types, not objects) using realloc as there is no similar function to realloc in C++ (although this can be done using a more C++ approach).

Answer (score 2):

I had played before with few C/C++ applications for computer graphics.
After so many time, some things are vanished and I missed them a lot.

The point is, that malloc and new, or free and delete, can work both,
especially for certain basic types, which are the most common.

For instance, a char array, can be allocated both with malloc, or new.
A main difference is, with new you can instantiate a fixed array size.

```
char* pWord = new char[5]; // allocation of char array of fixed size
```

You cannot use a variable for the size of the array in this case.
By the contrary, the malloc function could allow a variable size.

```
int size = 5; 
char* pWord = (char*)malloc(size);
```

In this case, it might be required a conversion cast operator.
For the returned type from malloc it's a pointer to void, not char.
And sometimes the compiler could not know, how to convert this type.

After allocation the memory block, you can set the variable values.
the memset function can be indeed slower for some bigger arrays.
But all the bites must be set first to 0, before assigning a value.
Because the values of an array could have an arbitrary content.

Suppose, the array is assigned with another array of smaller size.
Part of the array element could still have arbitrary content.
And a call to a memset function would be recomended in this case.

```
memset((void*)pWord, 0, sizeof(pWord) / sizeof(char));
```

The allocation functions are available for all C packages.
So, these are general functions, that must work for more C types.
And the C++ libraries are extensions of the older C libraries.
Therefore the malloc function returns a generic void* pointer.
The sructures do not have defined a new, or a delete operator.
In this case, a custom variable can be allocated with malloc.

The new and delete keywords are actually some defined C operators.
Maybe a custom union, or class, can have defined these operators.
If new and delete are not defined in a class, these may not work.
But if a class is derived from another, which has these operators,
the new and delete keywords can have the basic class behavior.

About freeing an array, free can be only used in pair with malloc.
Cannot allocate a variable with malloc, and then free with delete.

The simple delete operator references just first item of an array.
Because the pWord array can be also written as:

```
pWord = &pWord[0]; // or *pWord = pWord[0];
```

When an array must be deleted, use the delete[] operator instead:

```
delete[] pWord;
```

Casts are not bad, they just don't work for all the variable types.
A conversion cast is also an operator function, that must be defined.
If this operator is not defined for a certain type, it may not work.
But not all the errors are because of this conversion cast operator.

Also a cast to a void pointer must be used when using a free call.
This is because the argument of the free function is a void pointer.

```
free((void*)pWord);
```

Some errors can arise, because the size of the array is too small.
But this is another story, it is not because of using the cast.

With kind regards, Adrian Brinas

Answer (score 0):

The `new` and `delete` operators can operate on classes and structures, whereas `malloc` and `free` only work with blocks of memory that need to be cast.

Using `new/delete` will help to improve your code as you will not need to cast allocated memory to the required data structure.

Answer (score -4):

malloc() is used to dynamically assign memory in C
while the same work is done by new() in c++.
So you cannot mix coding conventions of 2 languages.
It would be good if you asked for difference between calloc and malloc()

Comment: You *can* (but almost always shouldn't) use `malloc` in C++.

Comment: You also missed the prime point that you should aim to avoid dynamic memory allocation, unless doing so through smart pointers. You are just setting your self up for pain other wise