# using Pointers to a series of integers in C++

Tags: c++, list, pointers

I am trying to make a c++ program with a class which holds integers on the "heap" and has only one method, pop() which returns the first item in the class and removes it. This is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class LinkList {
int *values; //pointer to integers stored in linklist
int number; // number of values stored in linklist
public:
LinkList(const int*, int); // Constructor (method declaration)
int pop(); // typically remove item from data structure (method declaration)

};

LinkList::LinkList(const int *v, int n){
number = n;
*values = *v;
int mypointer = 1;
while (mypointer<n) {
    *(values+mypointer) = *(v+mypointer);
    mypointer++;
}
}


int LinkList::pop() {
if (number>0) {
    int returnme = *values; //get the first integer in the linklist
    number--;
    values++; //move values to next address
    return returnme;
}
else {return -1;}
}



int main() {
int test[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
LinkList l1(test,5);
cout << l1.pop() << endl;
LinkList l2(test,5);
cout << l2.pop() << endl;
return 0;
}
```

The issue is that its failing at the line *values = *v, if i remove the 4th and 5th lines from the main method, I no longer get this issue, so its go to be a memory management thing.

What I want to do is to get values to point to a continuous bit of memory with integers in. I have tried to use arrays for this but keep just getting random memory addresses returned by pop()

Background: normal I programming in java, I've only be using C/C++ for 2 months, I'm using eclipse IDE in ubuntu, I can make very basic use of the debugger but currently I dont have functioning scroll bars in eclipse so I can't do somethings if they dont fit on my screen.

Comment: Its an exercise from a C++ course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*values = *v;
```

You dereference the `values` pointer in this line before initializing it. This is the source of the later errors, and the non-errors in the first three lines of `main` are simply due to luck. You have to allocate space via `values = new int[n]` and deallocate it in the destructor via `delete[] values`. `std::vector` does this work in a clean and exception-safe way for you.

Comment: how does `delete[] values` remove the values held in the array when it does know how long the array is ?

Comment: @Heidi: [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975792/how-does-delete-know-the-size-of-an-array)

Answer (score 4):

You are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer (`values`) at the line `*values = *v;` which is **undefined behavior (UB)**.  What this line says is "get the integer that `values` points to and assign to it the value pointed by `v`". The problem with this logic is that `values` doesn't yet point to anything. The result of this UB is the crash that you receive.

There are many other problems with this code, such as passing a `const int*` to the constructor with the intent of modifying those values. The biggest problem is that this is not an actual linked list.

Comment: Technically, the values in the const int pointer are not modified later on, but copied into internal storage in the "LinkList". So this is correct and just an attempt at building `std::vector`'s two-iterator constructor, but you are right about the other errors.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the problem is that you're incrementing an integer - mypointer, rather than a a pointer. If the integer requires more than one byte of space, then this might lead to errors. Could you try declaring a pointer and incrementing that instead?

Answer (score 1):

The `values` member variable is a pointer to uninitialized memory. Before you start copying numbers into it you have to point it to valid memory. For example:

```
LinkList::LinkList(const int *v, int n){
    number = n;
    values = new int[n]; // allocate memory
    int mypointer = 0;
    while (mypointer<n) {
        *(values+mypointer) = *(v+mypointer);
        mypointer++;
    }
}

LinkList::~LinkList() {
    delete values; // release memory
}
```

Also, why do you call this a linked list while in fact you are using a memory array to store your numbers?