# How do you declare and use an overloaded pool operator delete?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, delete-operator, memory-pool

I would like to know how to adapt [section 11.14 of the C++-FAQ-lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.14) to arrays.

Basically, I would want something like this:

```
class Pool {
public:
  void* allocate(size_t size) {...}
  void deallocate(void* p, size_t size) {...}
};

void* operator new[](size_t size, Pool& pool) { return pool.allocate(size); }
void operator delete[](void* p, size_t size, Pool& pool) { pool.deallocate(p, size); }

struct Foo {...};

int main() {
  Pool pool;

  Foo* manyFoos = new (pool) Foo [15];

  /* ... */

  delete [] (pool) manyFoos;
}
```

However, I have not been able to figure out the correct syntax to declare and call this `operator delete[] (pool)`. Can anybody help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible. Bjarne reasons that you'll never get it right figuring out the correct pool. His solution is: you must manually call all destructors and then figure out the correct pool to be able to deallocate the memory manually.

References:

Bjarne's FAQ: [Is there a placement delete?](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#placement-delete)

Relevant C++ standard sections:

3.7.3.2.2 Only member operator delete functions with an argument of size_t type are considered for delete expressions.

5.3.5.1 Delete expression syntax does not allow extra parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Call the dtors on the individual objects first and then use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) manyFoos[ i ]->~Foo();
operator delete[] (manyFoos, pool);
```

You can read the whole FAQ item again and you will find it there.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. How does this statement delete the array `manyFoos` ? And how does the compiler know to call `operator delete []`, not `operator delete`?

Comment: @Tobias: I had a typo. Fixed post.

Comment: @Tobias: When using the placement form you need to do what the compiler otherwise does for you automatically -- 1) call the dtor on the object(s) 2) free the memory. The first line of code takes care of #1. Now, the second line, takes care of freeing that part of the `pool` where your array objects came from.

Comment: There is no `placement delete` operator in C++. See:http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#placement-delete for a quick reference and http://informit.com./articles/article.aspx?p=30642&seqNum=3

Comment: Clarification: The placement delete form does not invoke any dtors, which is why we need the explicit dtor calls.