# What is the difference between "new" and "malloc" and "calloc" in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-management, malloc, heap-memory

What is the difference between "`new`" and "`malloc`"  and "`calloc`" and others in family?

(When) Do I need anything other than "`new`" ?

Is one of them implemented using any other?

Comment: If you're using the STL, you should rarely need to use explicit memory allocation at all.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240212/what-is-the-difference-between-new-delete-and-malloc-free

Comment: Check the duplicate linked question, as its answer is more complete: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240212/what-is-the-difference-between-new-delete-and-malloc-free

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`new` and `delete` are C++ specific features. They didn't exist in C. `malloc` is the old school C way to do things. Most of the time, you won't need to use it in C++.

- `malloc` allocates uninitialized memory. The allocated memory has to be released with `free`.
- `calloc` is like `malloc` but initializes the allocated memory with a constant (0). It needs to be freed with `free`.
- `new` initializes the allocated memory by calling the constructor (if it's an object). Memory allocated with `new` should be released with `delete` (which in turn calls the destructor). It does not need you to manually specify the size you need and cast it to the appropriate type. Thus, it's more modern and less prone to errors.

Comment: Is "scratch space" a term you have just invented?

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: I don't know. But I think I've read it somewhere... Glossary: scratch space: n. uninitialized memory :)

Comment: keeping c++ specific terminology, an array is an object too, and the ctors of all its sub-objects will be called.

Comment: I think it is confusing - we have enough terms in this area as it is. new allocates dynamic memory.

Comment: Edited to stick with C++ terminology to reduce the chance of confusion.

Comment: Scratch space is typically disk storage on a hard drive that is used for temporary memory, Ref http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-scratch-space.htm

Answer (score 24):

**`new`/`delete` + `new[]`/`delete[]`:**

- `new`/`delete` is the C++ way to allocate memory and deallocate memory from the heap.
- `new[]` and `delete[]` is the C++ way to allocate arrays of contiguous memory.
- Should be used because it is more type safe than `malloc`
- Should be used because it calls the constructor/destructor
- Cannot be used in a `realloc` way, but can use placement new to re-use the same buffer of data
- Data cannot be allocated with `new` and freed with `free`, nor `delete[]`

**`malloc`/`free` + family:**

- `malloc`/`free`/family is the C way to allocate and free memory from the heap.
- `calloc` is the same as `malloc` but also initializes the memory
- Should be used if you may need to reallocate the memory
- Data cannot be allocated with `malloc` and freed with delete nor delete[]

Also see my [related answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new/184540#184540)

Comment: @Martin York: I see now from the linked duplicate question. I like your lists better though :)  I think it is the bets format for these types of questions where you compare and contrast 2 things.  At least I always get high up votes for that type of formatted answers.

Answer (score 8):

- `new` allocates and calls to ctor (the order is unspecified), `delete` the dtor and frees the memory allocated by a call to new
- `malloc` only allocates some memory, and `free` deletes memory allocated by `malloc`
- `new` may be implemented using `malloc` (not required though by the standard)
- `calloc` does the same thing as `malloc` and also zero-initialises the newly allocated memory

As other posts have pointed out: `malloc`/`free` is part of C++ to be compatible with C.

Also see: [Stroustrup: new vs malloc](http://www.research.att.com/%7Ebs/bs_faq2.html#malloc)

Answer (score 6):

You don't need anything other than new.  It is a complete replacement for malloc in C++.

As for the difference: Malloc just allocates memory.  New allocated memory and calls the constructors.  Likewise free just releases the memory.  Delete releases the memory and calls the destructor.

A word of warning:  Don't mix the two idioms.  The results are undefined.

Comment: Click This Link http://www.ritambhara.in/difference-between-malloc-calloc-free-and-realloc-functions/

Answer (score 5):

Using new means that constructors will be called on the newly allocated memory. If the thing being allocated doesn't have constructors, new is functionally identical to malloc. and should normally be used in pereference to it.

new may or may not be implemented in terms of malloc - the C++ standard does not require either approach.

Answer (score 2):

the main difference between new and malloc I can recall is that you cannot reallocate memory allocated by new using realloc.  So if you wanted to increase/decrease the size of the memory block, you had to allocate a new block and copy everything over.

Calloc allows you to initialize the memory block you allocate while malloc does not.

Comment: In fact, this is the same for `malloc`. The `realloc` function does this most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

When you **new** an object, space for the object is not only allocated but the object's constructor is called. But this is the C++ way its done, **malloc** is the old version way in *C* of allocating memory. **calloc** is the same as **malloc**, except for it clears memory to all bits zero.