# what is difference between malloc and allocate

Tags: c++

i came across some code, that uses `allocate` extensively. For example,

```
char* recordDate = allocate<char>(20)
```

I have never used allocate before and hence the question, what is the difference between malloc and allocate?

One difference that i can tell, although i am unclear about its advantage, is that, malloc gives raw memory, where as it seems like allocate will give raw memory, but i dont have to cast the pointer to a specific type.

Comment: What exactly is `allocate`?

Comment: @Mehrdad It is part of std. See std::allocator::allocate http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocate

Comment: @CoryKlein That's not `allocate<>`, that's `std::allocator::allocate` (and I cannot image that *"code extensively using it"* always being part of an allocator implementation, especially this `recordData` example).

Comment: @CoryKlein: Wait, what? Which overload of `allocate` in `std::allocator<T>` takes in a type parameter like `char`, as shown in `allocate<char>`?

Answer (score 3):

From `allocate` documentation:

> Allocates `n * sizeof(T)` bytes of uninitialized storage by calling `::operator new(std::size_t)`, but **it is unspecified when and how this function is called**.

Also, from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807939/what-is-the-difference-between-new-and-malloc-and-calloc-in-c), you can see that `new` and `malloc` lead to different results.

Comment: So how is it different from malloc?

Comment: Which documentation is that? It looks like it's paraphrasing the specification of `std::allocator<T>::allocate`, but that's not what's in the question.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the difference is that with `allocate` you only have to give the number of items you want rather than the total size, and the return type is automatically cast to the correct type for you.

In C++ you should almost never use either, but prefer `new` which will call appropriate constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, these two functions do exactly the same thing. The only time you'll see a difference is if you start "looking at the inside of the function" or you run out of memory (`malloc` will return NULL, since `allocate` calls `::new`, it will throw a `bad_alloc` exception).

I think it's "better C++" to use `allocate` (if for no other reason than "You don't have to cast `allocate`).

Having said that, using `::new T[elements]` would be the normal way in C++, and outside of places where you have a passed in `allocator`, this is what you should be doing.

Comment: Really, what's that `allocate` template everybody is talking about (and the answerers seem to be taken as given)?