# Why is C++ treating assignment (=) as overloaded operator?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Why do I get this error:

```
test.cpp:11:28: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘*(((Test*)this)->Test::a_list + ((unsigned int)(((unsigned int)i) * 20u))) = Test::foo2()’
```

When I compile the below code (via `g++ test.cpp -o test`)

**test.cpp:**

```
#include "test.h"

Test::Test () {}

void Test::foo1 ()
{
   int i;
   a_list = ( A* ) malloc ( 10 * sizeof ( A ) ); 

   for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
      a_list [ i ] = foo2 ();
   }
}

A* Test::foo2 ()
{
   A *a;

   a = ( A* ) malloc ( sizeof ( A ) ); 

   return a;
}
```

**Test.h:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
   double x;
   double y;
   string z;
} A;

class Test
{
   public:
      Test ();
      void foo1 ();
   private:
      A* foo2 ();
      A *a_list;
};
```

Comment: You're using `malloc` to allocate struct that contains `std::string`, which is not a trivial type - its constructor won't be called.

Comment: Any reason you're writing C code in C++ instead of writing C++ code?

Comment: Somebody else's code (omxplayer)

Comment: @milleniumbug I appreciate that, but the error happens in the for loop

Comment: Maybe it got lost in all the parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a_list [ i ] = foo2 ();
```

`foo2()` returns a pointer to `A`, but `a_list[i]` is an object of type `A`.

Also, it would be better if you used `new` to allocate dynamic memory instead of `malloc`.

See [What is the difference between "new" and "malloc" and "calloc" in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807939/what-is-the-difference-between-new-and-malloc-and-calloc-in-c)

Instead of:

```
a_list = ( A* ) malloc ( 10 * sizeof ( A ) );
```

You can have:

```
a_list = new A[10];
```

And for deallocating memory, use

```
delete [] a_list;
```

An even better option is to use `std::vector<A>` . In this you do not have to manage memory allocations, de-allocations yourself as these are done automatically.

EDIT 2:

When you call `new A[10]`, then 10 objects of `struct A` are created dynamically on the heap and their constructors are called.

If you do not want to 'construct' 10 objects at this time, then I would suggest you use `std::vector<A>`.

You can just `push_back( object_of_type_A )` to the vector as you create it.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: Can I just swap `new` in for `malloc` =P Can you please demonstrate a small script that would do this for me?

Comment: I was not aware that `new` worked with structs as well

Comment: @puk - The only difference between struct and class is the default visibility: public for structs, private for classes.

Comment: @puk In C++, struct and class are identical, the only difference being that in struct, if you do not mention any access type, then the members are public by default, whereas in a class if you do not mention any access type, the members are private by default.

Comment: Wait I'm confused again, when you call `a_list = new A[10]` that initializes all the entries, when all I want to do is allocate space at the moment.

Comment: Mother of god, this is so complex. How about creating a default constructor, creating the array via `new A[10]` then going around and reinitializing everything, but this time with the 3 parameter constructor? I ask, because I am reading values from a file and creating new objects based on those values

Comment: @puk Ofcourse you can do that, except that the second 'constructor' that you call shall not be technically called a constructor, it will be a member function that changes the values of the variables of the object to new values.

Comment: Actually, you may very well call the constructor again to create a single temporary `A` object from those 3 parameters, and then assign this single object to the array: `array[5] = A{p1, p2, p3}`.