# Error reading characters of string error in malloc()ed object. Why?

Tags: c++

I'm working with C++ in Visual Studio.
I have a problem when using this structure:

```
struct TreeNode
{
    string info;
    TreeNode* left, * right;
};
typedef struct TreeNode* ExpTree;
```

like in this function:

```
ExpTree createNode(string info)
{
    TreeNode* temp;
    temp = (TreeNode*)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Out of space!\n";
        return (temp);
    }
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    temp->info = info;
    return temp;
};
```

When I try to run this in the main function:

```
ExpTree tree = NULL;
tree = createNode(expresie);
cout << tree->info;
```

it prints nothing and exits with this code: `-1073741819`.

After debugging I saw that the program stops on this line: `temp->info = info;`, saying `<Error reading characters of string>`.

I made a little research on this and I saw that this has to do more with a bad design of the code, and not with a certain problem with a single solution.

So what did I do wrong here?

Comment: Why do you use `malloc` here? `malloc` will only allocate memory, but not initialize any of the classes. Use `new` instead, or even better, standard containers and smart pointers.

Comment: Hi @churill, that seems plausible enough to make an answer, doesn't it?

Comment: @Yunnosch Probably, but at the same time I see that mistake so often. I believe there might be a good duplicate for it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "new" and "malloc" and "calloc" in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807939/what-is-the-difference-between-new-and-malloc-and-calloc-in-c) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-and-or-new) is also related.

Comment: I do think it answers. But I suspect that anybody who used `malloc()` in the first place might ask "If that is the difference, then why do I need to use it in my code?".

Comment: I just tried and it works! Thanks

Comment: Initially I tagged it with the both of them but the administration removed the C tag.

Comment: Not "administration", but you are still basically right (and I missed it). Yes, that probably means that I am a little alone with my "both" opinion. Wise, to not follow my proposal. But thanks for following my other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the proposed duplicate technically does answer the question.
But here is some specifics on how that explains the problem here.

C "strings", which is not actually a thing there, are only memory containing `char`, usually terminated with `'\0'`. What ever is done with them, is done by functions which expect nothing but `char`s in memory.

C++ `std::strings` are different, they are objects, with methods, overloaded operators etc.
They do need initialisation or will fail in almost all use cases, like you have observed.

The init is done with `new()` not with `malloc()`.
That is why you should use `new()` and why (as you have confirmed by now) it solves your problem.

Comment: Good point, yes, that's one step further than the duplicate :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution. Use following code:

```
TreeNode* temp = new TreeNode();
//temp = (TreeNode*)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
```

Now the explanation. `malloc` only allocates memory of the size specified. It does not initializes it. In your case when you use `string` in the structure it is a class which needs initialization and without proper initialization the behavior of assignment is undefined.

using `new` is reconnended because it makes sure that not only the structure but all its components inclusing `string info;` gets initialized properly.