# How to free() a malloc()'d structured correctly?

Tags: c, pointers, free, malloc

i have a structure malloc()'d, and after using them, i want to free() it, but my program freezes out here. Can anyone tell me, what i am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
struct data  
{  
char *filename;  
char *size;  
};   
 //primarypcs is a long type variable
struct data *primary = (struct data *)malloc( primarypcs * sizeof( struct data ) );  
memset( primary, 0, sizeof(struct data *) * primarypcs );  
...
...
...
for ( i = 0; i < primarypcs; i++ )  
{
   free( primary[i].filename );  //<----my program freezes here
   free( primary[i].size );      //<----or here
}
free( primary );
```

Thanks in advance!

kampi

EDIT:

How can i correctly malloc memory for filename and size?

EDIT2:

Sorry, but i was in a hurry, and i didn't told you all the information that you need. Let me do it now :) Basicly, i want create an application, which gets the file list of two given drives/folders and then compares them. I thought (and still do), that the easiest way is, when i store the filenames and their size in a structure like mentioned above. So i have to allocate memory dynamically (i think this what they call it) for filename and size and of corse for the structure too.

Comment: I don't see you allocating memory for `filename` and `size`.

Comment: Yeah, there's a bug in your code: in the malloc you use sizeof(struct data) which seems correct, yet in memset you use sizeof(struct data*) which is half the size.

This means that you've only zero-ed half the memory and the last 1/2 of the memory will barf when you try to free it.

The answer should be free(primary); and nothing more

Comment: If this is C++, you should be using new and delete.

Comment: @Xorlev :I have already mentioned that in my answer. See my answer below.

Comment: You need to select either C++ or C as the language. Your sample is in C, not C++.

Comment: Based upon your second edit, you want `size` to be of an integral type, such as `size_t`, not `char *`.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not presenting the entire code, where a lot of things can go wrong, but one error is already obvious. The line

```
memset( primary, 0, sizeof(struct data *) * primarypcs );
```

is not doing what you think it is doing. It is not zeroing the entire array due to type mistake in `sizeof`. It was most likely supposed to be

```
memset( primary, 0, sizeof(struct data) * primarypcs );
```

Note no `*` under `sizeof`. Because of this error, most of the pointers in your array contain garbage as their initial values. If you don't set them to something meaningful in the omitted code, your calls to `free` will receive garbage arguments and fail.

In general, to reduce the chance of such errors it is best to avoid mentioning type names in your program, except in declarations. Since your question is tagged C++ (even though it surely looks like C), it is not possible to get rid of type casts on `malloc`, but otherwise I'd say that the following looks better

```
struct data *primary = (struct data *) malloc( primarypcs * sizeof *primary );   
memset( primary, 0, primarypcs * sizeof *primary );
```

And, as a side note, if your code was intended to be C++, you could get the same result in a much more elegant, compact and portable way

```
data *primary = new data[primarypcs]();
```

Of course in this case you'll have to deallocate the memory using the appropriate C++ functionality instead of `free`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks you for your help. This was one of my mistakes, btut after correcting my code by your answer, my program still freezed out. Later i realized i haver mistyped one of my variable, and i only allocated memory for 5 items, however i inserted more than 5 items into the structure. Thanks you again!

Answer (score 3):

How are the strings in the structure allocated?  If they are statically assigned to constants, then don't free them that way, and all that's needed is `free (primary);`  Freeing something which was not malloc'd will give the heap manager a heart seizure.

If the string pointers are set by malloc() or calloc(), that is the proper way.

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing this in C++, you (almost certainly) should not use something like:

```
data *primary = new data[primarypcs]();
```

Instead, you should use something like:

```
struct data {
    std::string filename;
    std::string size;
};

std::vector<data> primary(primarypcs);
```

In this case, you can typically handle the memory management much more simply: define the vector in the scope where it's needed, and when it goes out of scope, the memory will be released automatically.

Use of array new (like `new x[y]`) in C++ is something you're better off without. Once upon a time (15 years ago or so) it was nearly the only tool available, so its (grudging) use was almost unavoidable -- but that day is long past, and it's been at last 10 years since there was really a good reason to use it.

Since there's inevitably a comment about "except in implementing something like vector", I'll point out that, no, even when you're implementing vector you don't use array new -- you (indirectly, via an allocator) use `::operator new` to allocate raw memory, placement new to create objects in that memory, and explicit dtor calls to destroy objects.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, there are two obviously wrong things in the snippet you've shown:

1. You don't allocate memory for `filename` and `size` members of the structs just allocated,
2. Your `memset()` call uses the wrong size.

Your `memset()` call could be simplified and corrected by:

```
memset(primary, 0, primarypcs * sizeof *primary);
```

There is another subtle problem with your code: C standard doesn't guarantee that all-bits-zero is the null pointer constant (i.e., NULL), so memset() isn't the right way to set a pointer to `NULL`.  A portable way of doing what you want to do is:

```
size_t i;
for (i=0; i < primarypcs; ++i) {
    primary[i].filename = NULL;
    primary[i].size = NULL;
}
```

To allocate memory for `filename` and `size`, it depends upon what you want.  Let's say you determine that `filename` needs `n` bytes, and `size` needs `m`.  Then, your loop changes to something like this:

```
size_t i;
for (i=0; i < primarypcs; ++i) {
    size_t n, m;
    /* get the values of n and m */
    primary[i].filename = malloc(n * sizeof *primary[i].filename);
    primary[i].size = malloc(m * sizeof *primary[i].size);
}
```

You can omit the multiplication with `sizeof *primary[i].filename` and `sizeof *primary[i].size` from the above if you want: C guarantees that `sizeof(char)` is 1.  I wrote the above for completeness and for the case when `filename` and `size` change types.

Also, note that if `filename` is a string of length `k`, then you need `(k+1)` bytes for it, because of the terminating `0` (so `n == k+1` above).

If I were to take a guess, you want `size` to store the length of the corresponding `filename`?  If that is the case, `size` should not be a `char *` but a `size_t`.  But since I don't know how you plan on using `filename` and `size`, I am not sure.

Be sure to check for the return value of `malloc()`.  It returns `NULL` for failure.  I omitted the check from the above code for simplicity.

Your post has been tagged C++ too, so if you are willing to use C++, there is a C++ solution available too.

Comment: Hi!
How should i correctly allocate memory for filename, and size?

Comment: Hi! size is char* for a purpose. I get the file's size in a long, but later i have to use it as a char, so i convert it from int to char, and then store it in the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing  the for loop at the bottom of your code with `free (primary);` should work.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have not explicitly allocated memory for `filename` and `size`. So trying to do `free( primary[i].filename );` or `free( primary[i].size );` would invoke **Undefined Behavior**.

Just `free(primary)` is enough.

**EDIT**:

This question has been tagged C++. So the C++ way is to use `new` instead of `malloc` for user defined types.

For differences between `new` and `malloc` have a look at [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240212/what-is-the-difference-between-new-delete-and-malloc-free)

In **C++**, you just need to write

```
 data *primary = new data[primarypcs](); //() for value initialization
```

Comment: the sample code can be regarded as ok, presuming they individually malloc the filename. having a malloc'ed 'size' looks suspiciously buggy tho, a size_t would probably suit better (unless it really is a char string)

Answer (score 0):

This fixes your problem in memset, which caused all sorts of issues for you.

```
memset( primary, 0, sizeof(struct data) * primarypcs );
```

In short, you left uninitialized memory at the end of your 'primary' structure.

Answer (score 0):

You're failing to memset the entire array resulting in a garbage memory pointer being freed. Use calloc instead of malloc/memset to avoid this mistake:

```
struct data *primary = calloc(primarypcs, sizeof(struct data));
```

This both allocates *and clears* the memory.
If you want to initialize all the `struct data` entries too:

```
for (i = 0; i < primarypcs; ++i) {
    primary[i].filename = malloc(...);
    primary[i].size = malloc(...);
}
```

(You don't describe what filename are size are, so I leave the ... in for you to fill in).