# what is return type of new in c++?

Tags: c++

in C, `malloc()` returns `void*`. But in C++, what does `new` return?

```
double d = new int;
```

Comment: @Suma: While I basically agree with your sentiments towards kam's questions, I believe that this one is genuine and the important distinction between a _new expression_ and the _new operator_ is hard to come by when googling for "operator new".

Comment: @Suma: A poor question can still lead to good answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240212/what-is-the-difference-between-new-delete-and-malloc-free

Comment: There's a bit of a semantic error here. Since `new` is a language keyword and not a function, it doesn't "return" anything. The question is kind of like asking what does `1` return or what does `+` return? Well, it depends. The right question is to ask what the rules are for that expressions involving it evaluate to.

Answer (score 42):

There's two things you have to distinguish. One is a ***new expression***. It is the expression `new T` and its result is a `T*`. It does two things: First, it calls the *new operator* to *allocate memory*, then it invokes the *constructor* for T. (If the constructor aborts with an exception, it will also call the *delete operator*.)

The aforementioned ***new operator***, however, comes in several flavours. The most prominent is this one:

```
void* operator new(std::size_t);
```

You could call it explicitly, but that's rarely ever done.

There are other forms of the *new operator*, for example for arrays

```
void* operator new[](std::size_t);
```

or the so-called *placement new* (which really is a fake-new, since it doesn't allocate):

```
void* operator new(void*, std::size_t);
```

Comment: For example int *p = new int, it returns int*, then how signature has void*?

Comment: Great answer to a silly question. The poster does not seem to have any idea of how "new" fits into the language. The answer explains this very nicely.

Comment: "int p = new int, it returns int," It does not. I returns int * (pointer to int).

Comment: @kam: `<sigh>` Read again. `new int` is a __new expression__. The language defines that it returns an `int*`. Among other things it also calls the __new operator__, which, yes, returns a `void*`, because it just allocates raw storage. The constructor (empty for `int`) turns raw storage into an initialized object. You could think of this as the transformation from `void*` to `int*` if you like.

Comment: `new T` does not evaluate to `T*` for arrays, though.

Comment: @sbi, if `T` is an array type, then `new T` is not compatible with `T*`. That's all i want to say :) It doesn't depend on whether you write brackets or not. It depends on the type. (imagine that `T` can be a typedef for an array type or a template parameter passed an array type). Thus in a template `T * t = new T;` is not correct for arrays.

Comment: Ouch. Indeed, `T` could be a `typedef` for a array. I would have never thought of this. Well, considering the question, I still guess we can skip over this detail, but I marvel at your attention for detail.

Comment: @sbi Hi I am new to C++, I am not able to find simple code which shows operator overloading of new operator can you give link of such code here and also `new int[20]` like this way we call new operator via new expression but in new operator it's like `void* operator new[](std::size_t);` here where is the data type like `int` and also extra `(std::size_t):` is there so why such differnce . might be it is simple but I am not understanding. please explain this .

Comment: @AbhishekMane: When you're new to C++, you shouldn't directly use dynamic memory, let alone overload the **`new`** and **`delete`** operators. If you ant to do that, though, there is an answer regarding this in the (a bit outdated) [C++ operator overloading FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/140719).

Answer (score 15):

Type of value returned from both `new Type[x]` and `new Type` is `Type *`. Your example `double d = new int` contains two errors:

- you need to assign the result into a pointer, like this: `double *d = new int`
- the pointer needs to be a pointer to Type or something to which can a pointer to Type be converted using implicit conversions: `int *d = new int` or `void *d = new int`