# 'new' operator understanding

Tags: c++

need detailed explanation on the 'new' operator in C++.
Can somebody explain why the following works:

```
int *n = new int(10);  // initialize the pointer to integer as '10'
cout << *n;            // o/p -> 10
```

but this does not work?

```
int p = new int (10);  // error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: Why do you expect the second to work?  `new` returns a pointer.

Comment: duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726356/the-new-operator-in-c-pointer-question

Comment: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [the "new" operator in c++, pointer question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726356/the-new-operator-in-c-pointer-question)

Comment: So what is the difference between `int *n` and `int p`?

Answer (score 0):

new operator used with pointers, not int type
so

```
   int x = 5;
   int *p = &x;
   int *q = new int(4);
```

and you can use it with classes struct, so on but not pure types
I mean just int char .. etc.

this is the declaration of new :

```
  void* operator new[] (std::size_t size);
  void* operator new[] (std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t& nothrow_value) noexcept;
  void* operator new[] (std::size_t size, void* ptr) noexcept;
```

as what you see it's return pointer type void so you cann't in c/c++
write

```
  int x = p; // error : invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int'
```

which is the same as what you did.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite evident from the error message itself..
**error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int'**

*Since "new" returns a pointer if it is successful*. That's why you are getting an error when you are trying to assign it to an int.