# How operator new calls the constructor of class?

Tags: c++

I know that, new operator will call the constructor of class.

But how it's happening, what is ground level techniques used for this.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697892/what-is-return-type-of-new-in-c/2697929#2697929) to a similar question. Basically, you need to understand that there's a __new expression__ and a __new operator__, which are related, but not the same. A _new expression_ first invokes _operator new_ and then the _constructor_.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how I imagine it:

```
T* the_new_operator(args)
{
    void* memory = operator new(sizeof(T));
    T* object;
    try
    {
        object = new(memory) T(args);   // (*)
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        operator delete(memory);
        throw;
    }
    return object;
}
```

(*) Technically, it's not really calling placement-new, but as long as you don't overload that, the mental model works fine :)

Comment: This is very simplified and doesn't reflect the fact that when an exception is thrown all *completely constructed* subobjects are run destructors on. Although I can't imagine how you could illustrate that in the preudocode.

Comment: @sharp But that's what any constructor always does, regardless of where the memory comes from. It is nothing that the new operator has to do specifically.

Answer (score 4):

It's not really the new operator that calls the constructor. It is more the compiler that translate the following line:

```
MyClass * mine = new MyClass();
```

Into the following:

```
MyClass * mine = malloc(sizeof(MyClass));  // Allocates memory
mine->MyClass();                           // Calls constructor
```

With other error handling code that other answers have noted.

Comment: No, not ever `malloc()` - `operator new()` is what is called. Big difference (for example, you can overload `operator new()` per class).

Comment: True, but I used `malloc()` for the simplicity, and to try to indicate that it is only a matter of allocating a bunch of memory. Nothing else. Overloading `operator new` is more advanced considerations I woudn't use in an explanation for lower level questions as the current.

Comment: Sadly, the name `malloc` fits the purpose a lot better than `operator new`, because the latter is often confused with the new operator... :(

Answer (score 1):

The compiler generates machine code for that. When the compiler sees

```
CSomeClass* object = new CSomeClass();
```

(*new statement*) it generates code that calls the appropriate `operator new()` (which allocates memory), calls the right constructor, calls destructors of all fully constructed subobjects in case of exception, calls `operator delete()` in case an exception occurs during construction. All this is done by extra machine code generated by the C++ compiler for that simply looking statement.