# Why is the new operator allowed to return *void to every pointer-type?

Tags: c++

In C++ it is not allowed to assign an void* pointer to any integral pointer without an explicit cast. This requires the use of an static_cast.

But what is with this:

```
int* iptr = new int;
```

I know that new operator is defined as following:

```
void* operator new(size_t);
```

How does C++ handle this?
I know that this is a basic question, but important. I also know that low-level code must use void. But how can this assignment be legal? iptr is a pointer to an int and new returns a pointer to void, which should trigger a message like "error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]".

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697892/what-is-return-type-of-new-in-c ; operator new and new expressions are not the same thing.

Comment: Also, this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941888/how-operator-new-calls-the-constructor-of-class - I believe both of these answer your question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have confused the **new** operator and the **operator new** function. No problem, everybody does. They are almost the same, except that they are different.

The function `void* operator new(size_t)` grabs a block of raw, untyped memory from whatever tree it grows on, and returns it to the program.

```
void* raw_memory = ::operator new(42);
```

It is an ordinary function with somewhat weird name.

The **new** operator is not a function and not a function call. It's a separate language construct. It takes raw memory (normally, one returned by the `void* operator new(size_t)` function) and turns it into an object by calling a constructor. It then returns a properly typed pointer to the newly-created object.

```
Fish* f = new Fish;
```

**UPDATE** Naturally, there is also the **delete** operator (the opposite of the **new** operator) and the `void operator delete(void*)` function (the opposite of the `void* operator new(size_t)` function).

There are also the **new[]** operator, the **delete[]** operator, the `void* operator new[](size_t)` function, and the `void operator delete[](void*)` function; they deal with arrays of objects (as opposed to individual objects).

There are also so-called "placement new" forms that do not call any of the `operator new` functions for fresh memory, but instead require an explicit pointer to raw memory. They have no corresponding built-in "delete" forms. You can roll your own if you are so inclined, but I refuse to talk about any of this while being sober.

Comment: +1 for "They are almost the same, except that they are different."

Comment: @Seth: No, `delete void_ptr;` is undefined behaviour. You'd use `::operator delete(void_ptr_from_operator_new);`

Comment: Naturally, there is the **delete** operator (the opposite of the **new** operator) and the `void operator delete(void*)` function (the opposite of the `operator new` function). There are also the **new[]** operator, the **delete[]** operator, the `void* operator new[](size_t)` function, and the `void operator delete[](void*)` function. There are also "placement new" forms that do not have corresponding "delete".

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it seem to be clear for me. Because even Debugging with gdb doesn't "show" me this.

Comment: "placement new" does call `operator new()`, but it calls a different overload with more arguments.