# Does new return (void *) in C++?

Tags: c++

This is a simple question :

Does using new operator return a pointer of type (void *)?
Referring to [What is the difference between new/delete and malloc/free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240212/what-is-the-difference-between-new-delete-and-malloc-free) answer - it says `new returns a fully typed pointer while malloc void *`

But according to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/

```
throwing (1)    
void* operator new (std::size_t size) throw (std::bad_alloc);
nothrow (2) 
void* operator new (std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t& nothrow_value) throw();
placement (3)   
void* operator new (std::size_t size, void* ptr) throw();
```

which means it returns a pointer of type (void *), if it returns (void *) I have never seen a code like MyClass *ptr = (MyClass *)new MyClass;

I have got confused .

**EDIT**

As per http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/  example

```
std::cout << "1: ";
  MyClass * p1 = new MyClass;
      // allocates memory by calling: operator new (sizeof(MyClass))
      // and then constructs an object at the newly allocated space

  std::cout << "2: ";
  MyClass * p2 = new (std::nothrow) MyClass;
      // allocates memory by calling: operator new (sizeof(MyClass),std::nothrow)
      // and then constructs an object at the newly allocated space
```

So `MyClass * p1 = new MyClass` calls `operator new (sizeof(MyClass))` and since `throwing (1)

void* operator new (std::size_t size) throw (std::bad_alloc);` it should return `(void *)` if I understand the syntax correctly.

Thanks

Comment: [Shameless plug](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8962536/775806)

Comment: [cppreference entry for new-expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new)

Comment: @DyP Ok.. got it .. what u meant to say `The new-expression (new int) uses an allocation function (operator new). The allocation function only provides storage, new-expression new type-id returns a pointer to type-id (or throws)`.. Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are confusing `operator new` (which does return `void*`) and the `new` operator (which returns a fully-typed pointer).

```
void* vptr = operator new(10); // allocates 10 bytes
int* iptr = new int(10); // allocate 1 int, and initializes it to 10
```

Comment: Standard refers to the latter one as *new-expression*.

Comment: One way of thinking about it is that the `new` expression "converts" or "casts" memory to objects: void pointer goes in, object pointer comes out.

Comment: john Referring to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/  `std::cout << "1: ";
  MyClass * p1 = new MyClass;
      // allocates memory by calling: operator new (sizeof(MyClass))
      // and then constructs an object at the newly allocated space`
it calls `operator new (sizeof(MyClass))` , so basically it should return `(void *)` as per your argument

Comment: @GauravK The new-expression (`new int`) _uses_ an allocation function (`operator new`). The allocation function only provides storage, new-expression `new type-id` returns a _pointer to type-id_ (or throws).

Comment: @KerrekSB - "converts", not "casts". `<g>` In my usual pedantic mode: a **cast** is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a **conversion**.

Answer (score 0):

`void *` does not need to be cast to a higher type during assignment only old c code from before the existence of `void *` requires casting as the old malloc signature returned a `char *` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`new` will return a pointer of what ever type you are making an instance of. `operator new` return pointer to void. `new` is fairly common while `operator new` is a little more unique.