# What compilation mechanism casts the result of new operator?

Tags: c++, new-operator

Apparently, the `new` operator returns `void*`. So I was wondering what mechanism allows `void*` casting to `A*` when calling `new A()` to create a new instance of class `A`.

To illustrate:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A
{
public:
    A() {}    
};

void* createA()
{
    return new A();
}

int main()
{
    A* a1 = new A();
    A* a2 = createA();
    delete a1;
    delete a2;
}
```

`A* a1 = new A()` compiles fine (obviously).

`A* a2 = createA()` does not reporting error: `error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'A*'` (obviously too...).

Actually, the first one also does a conversion from `void*` to `A`. What mechanism or rule allows the first conversion and rejects the second one?

That's probably a stupid question....if so, sorry about that.

Comment: What about : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16345393/1870760

Comment: @JameyD: Right, it's actually not the `operator new` that is being used here. I missed this SO topic when looking for that before asking the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is a [`new` expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new), which in turn invokes [`operator new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) (followed by the appropriate conversion), plus the constructor.

From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new):

```
::(optional) new (placement_params)(optional) ( type ) initializer(optional)
```

> Attempts to create an object of type, denoted by the **type-id** type ...

It won't work if you manually invoke `operator new`, e.g.

```
A* a2 = operator new(sizeof(A));
```

won't compile either.

Comment: You mean it's an `expression` and the compiler silently transforms this into a call to the `operator` + a `cast`?

Comment: @jpo38 Yes, most likely. It is not just a plain call to `operator new`.

Comment: Got it. It makes sense and this question was probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345340/does-new-return-void-in-c/16345393#16345393 references by James D

Comment: @jpo38 Oh yes, it is probably a dupe.

Comment: @jpo38 - there is no **cast**. There is a **conversion**. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. That makes it an explicit conversion. The compiler can also do implicit conversions, i.e., conversions that are not signaled by a cast.

Comment: @PeteBecker You're absolutely right, corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no cast here.

When the compiler sees a `new` expression, it first invokes the appropriate `new` operator (depending on the type and the arguments to the `new` keyword). That returns a pointer to a block of raw memory; such pointers are conventionally typed as `void*` since they do not refer to any object.

Then the appropriate constructors are executed (depending on the constructor arguments), starting with the base classes. The first step in executing a constructor is default-initializing the raw memory into which the object will be constructed. That includes initializing any internal metadata required by the object, such as its vtable if it includes a virtual method. Once that is finished, the memory region contains a nascent object, so `this` can be created with the correct type. Then the rest of the constructor can be executed (which might use `this`, either implicitly or explicitly).

Once all the constructors have been executed, the value of the `new` expression is the (typed) value of `this`.