# Difference between new(size_t) and new[](size_t)

Tags: c++, new-operator

I am trying to understand the difference between new(size_t) and new operator.

```
1. A* pa = new A(); // allocates sizeof(A) and initializes A
delete pa;

2. A* aa = new A[10]; // allocates sizeof(A)*10 and initializes all As
delete[] aa;

3. void* pv = ::operator new(5); // allocates 5 bytes using "new" as allocator
delete pv;

4. void* pav = ::operator new[](5); // allocates 5 bytes using "new[]" as allocator
delete[] pav;
```

What is the difference between (3) and (4) besides using new or new[]? From what I understand both simply allocates 5 bytes.

Also, I don't understand *in this case* why it is important to call delete[] and not delete (not just because I use new[] and not new, but what happens differently).

Comment: In most cases it won't matter, since the implementation will call `free` anyway. The Standard doesn't require the use of `malloc` and `free` though, so calling `delete[]` on `new` and the other way around is left as UB, which makes a program relying on this inherently broken.

Comment: Things will be different if `A` has a destructor.

Comment: `delete pv` in your example exhibits undefined behavior, I'm pretty sure. The complement to `::operator new(5)` is `::operator delete(pv);` Same with `pav`.

Comment: @RaymondChen no, OP asked about raw memory allocation/deallocation

Comment: You can check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8962467/1485885) for more about the `::operator new`