# Using 'new' in a template class is type safe?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm working on my own vector implementation, and one of the guys said on IRC, using 'new' to allocate memory in a template class isn't type safe. For example in this code:

```
// resize array when needed
template <class T>
void myVector<T>::resize()
{
    vCapacity += 5;
    T* temp = new T[vCapacity]();

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < vCapacity; i++) temp[i] = vArray[i];

    delete [] vArray;
    vArray = temp;
    temp = nullptr;
}
```

Is this true? When I learned C++, nobody mentioned this, and if I am not mistaken, when a compiler compiles a template class/function, it will replace the 'T's with the right types.

Comment: No idea what "the guy" mean. Maybe he mixed it up with Java's generics, but C++ templates do generate type-safe code.

Comment: Makes no sense to me. It's often said that `new` shouldn't be used at all if possible, but that's not related to templates.

Comment: aside: std::vector doesn't increase it's size linearly  (`+= 5`), but exponentially (`*= 2`); since it saves the cost of copying the objects multiple times which can be very expensive.

Comment: @UKMonkey Infact with a O(1) increase the overall performance of this implementation is on average O(n^2) while with an exponential increase it gets back to a more civilized O(n)

Comment: Not sure what by "not type safe" means in this context. Could he mean that it makes the resize function work only for `T` that are default constructible and not compile at all otherwise?

Comment: @Quentin @HolyBlackCat I think his mind is on `operator new` and its `void*` return-type. In that case improper casting will cause problems.

Comment: I mean, when the compiler will compile this code, will 'new' allocate memory space for the right type? Sorry, my english is bad:) Looks like the guy mistaken 'new' for '::operator new'.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but that `temp = nullptr;` at the end of the function doesn't accomplish anything. `temp` goes away immediately after that assignment.

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct. `new` returns a ["properly typed pointer"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8962536/8701826) , i.e. a `T*` to the allocated memory. It is as type safe as writing `new int`.

However, the more obscure `::operator new` (which is not the same as `new`) returns a `void*`, but can be statically cast to a `T*`. Even this is type safe as long as you let it be type safe (by not trying something potentially dangerous, like `reinterpret_cast`ing the pointer).

Also, when you instantiate `template <class T> vector` with `T` and use `T` consistently in the `vector` (allocation, deallocation, pointer arithmetic, ...), there is only ever one type involved - `T`. It's as safe as writing the whole `vector` with an explicit type (non-generic vector).

This also holds for `delete` and `operator delete`.

---

You had an additional question

> when the compiler will compile this code, will 'new' allocate memory space for the right type?

Yes. It will allocate memory for the type you supply. If you ask for memory to store 10x 32-bit `int`s, you'll get an `int*` to the first `int` of the 320bits of memory. If you ask for 10x n-bit `MyClass`es, you'll get a `MyClass*` to the first `MyClass` in the 10n bits of memory. This is a good working model.

A sidenote: type is a language construct. It does not exist in memory. The closest thing is saying that types exist implicitly by the intended use of different instructions (iadd, idivq, fadd, fdiv, ...). But this is somewhat beyond the point (if you're interested - take a look at assembly language and processor design).

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will generate some temporary function like this if you call it on a vector of int:

```
void myVector_int::resize()
{
  vCapacity += 5;
  int* temp = new int[vCapacity]();

  for (unsigned i = 0; i < vCapacity; i++) temp[i] = vArray[i];

  delete [] vArray;
  vArray = temp;
  temp = nullptr;
}
```

and thus this is in fact a "normal" function with a "normal" type which makes it perfectly type safe. So you are perfectly right that the compiler replaces the T with the actual type.