# how virtual functions work and what happens to new return type when assigned?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, virtual-functions

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Father
{
public:
  int a=99;
  void MakeAThing(){ cout<<"MakeAThing of father called"<<endl;}
  virtual void MakeAThing2(){ cout<<"MakeAThing2 of father called"<<endl;}
};
class Child : public Father
{
public:
  int b=11;
  void MakeAThing(){ cout<<"MakeAThing of child called"<<endl;}
  virtual void MakeAThing2(){ cout<<"MakeAThing2 of child called"<<endl;}
};

int main(){

  Father *obj;

  obj = new Child();
  obj->MakeAThing();// MakeAThing of Father is called

  //code to find out if  obj becomes a Child* after new
  Father fa  
  fa=*obj;
  cout <<fa.b<<endl; // error: 'Class Father' has no member 'b'
  //which means fa remains an object of Class Father


  Father *obj2;
  obj2 = new Child();
  obj2->MakeAThing2();// MakeAThing2 of Child is called
return 1;
}
```

Can someone explain what is going on in the main?
My try:

obj is a pointer to an object of type Father

In `obj= new Child();` new allocates memory for an object of type Child and returns a pointer to void: *void, right?, so is obj being converted to a *void type or is it remaining a *Father type ?  why?

In `obj->MakeAThing();` MakeAThing of Father is called, why?

In `obj2->MakeAThing2();` how come the keyword virtual makes the call MakeAThing2 refer to that of Child instead of that of father?

Comment: `new Child()` returns a `Child*`, not a `void*`

Comment: "how come the keyword virtual makes the call MakeAThing2 refer to that of Child instead of that of father" - Because that's the very purpose of `virtual` - to provide a way for a derived class to override functionality of the base class.

Comment: @ UnholySheep, I think I read new had return type void*, If I do new int, the return type would the be a int*? so does it  change every time?

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver "_I think I read new had return type void*_" Where did you read that? Are you confusing `std::malloc` with `new`?

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius yeah, probably because I come from C. So is the return type of new variable, depending on what type it is acting on?

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver One could learn that, by reading the documentation of [new expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new). Additionally, to make matters confusing, there exists [`operator new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new), but it's invoked, behind the scenes, by `new` expression, which you, actually, are using here. To read about the difference between them, you can, additionally, read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962467/why-is-the-new-operator-allowed-to-return-void-to-every-pointer-type

Answer (score 1):

The static type of the both pointers is `Father *`.

```
Father *obj;
Father *obj2;
```

So when you will try to call a member function the compiler will search its declaration in the class Father.

As a result in this statement

```
obj->MakeAThing();
```

there is called the member function of the class Father.

In this call

```
obj2->MakeAThing2();
```

the compiler will call the overriding virtual function defined in the class Child due to calling the function using the table of pointers to virtual functions. As the dynamic type of the pointer is `Child *` then the compiler will find the pointer to the virtual function in the object of the type Child.

Comment: what about obj = new Child() and obj2 = new Child(); , isn't this changing obj and making it a Child object?... and what do you mean with  "static type"? , I am not using the static keyword anywhere

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver obj and obj2 are pointers. They are not objects of the class. Their static type is Father. So the declarations of the called member functions will be searched in the parent class.

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver Yes the both pointers point to objects of the type Child. That is the dynamic type of the pointers is Child *. It is due to the dynamic type of the pointers the virtual function from the class Child will be called.

Comment: Static type - unchanging at runtime. `Father *` is a `Father *` Period. It will not change from being a pointer to a `Father`. The type that the pointer **points at** is dynamic. It could be anything derived from `Father` and this will not be known until runtime.

Comment: @ Vlad from Moscow I added a piece of code to find out if  obj (of type Father*) becomes a Child* after new(see code above), and the result is that it remains a Father object, So it's not true that both pointers point to objects of type Child.

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver In these statements   Father fa  
  fa=*obj; you have gotten an object of the type Father You declared the object of the type Father. So what are you expecting?.

Comment: @ Vlad from Moscow I was expecting that  obj = new Child() would make obj a pointer to Child as you said, so  that in fa=*obj ,   fa gets the Child value pointed by obj, converting fa into a Child

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver The subobject of the type Father of the object of the type Child is assigned to the object of the type Father. It is called slicing.

Comment: There is no such thing as the dynamic type of a pointer. (It isn't clear that there is such thing as the dynamic type of anything, either. But that's another point.)