# Difference between delete() function and delete operator in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers

I know delete operator used to deallocate the memory allocated by new keyword.  delete() function also do the same job in below code .what is difference  between delete() function and delete operator in below code?

```
int* ptr = new int(5); 
int* ptr1 = new int(5); 
delete ptr; 
delete (ptr1);
```

Comment: `delete (ptr)` isn't a function call. It's the same as `delete ptr` the parentheses don't do anything here

Comment: There is no delete function. `(ptr)` is an expression in parntheses, and that is the operand to `delete`.

Comment: `delete` takes an expression. Both `ptr` and `(ptr)` are valid expressions.

Comment: To call the `delete` *function* you need to use its complete name: [`operator delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete). As in `operator delete(ptr)`.

Comment: You can think of it this way : `delete ptr;` is the same as `delete (ptr);` in the same way `int x = 1;` is the same as `int x = (1);`.

Comment: As for the difference between the `delete` operator and the `operator delete` function, the first (the `delete` operator) first calls the objects destructor (if applicable) and then calls the `operator delete` function to free the memory; The `operator delete` function only free the memory. The `operator delete` function is essentially the same (and probably calls) the [`std::free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/free) function.

Comment: [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962467/why-is-the-new-operator-allowed-to-return-void-to-every-pointer-type/8962536#8962536)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> delete() function also do the same job in below code
>
> ```
> delete (ptr1);
> ```

That is not a "delete function". That is a delete expression where the "operand" is a parenthesised expression.

> what is difference [between `delete ptr;` and `delete (ptr1);`]

The difference is the same as in the following expressions:

```
1 +  2
1 + (2)
```

In other words, there is no functional difference. The parentheses are redundant.