# Deleting an object constructed without new (C++)

Tags: c++, new-operator, delete-operator

I came across an article on `new` / `operator new`:

[The many faces of operator new in C++](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/02/17/the-many-faces-of-operator-new-in-c)

I couldn't understand the following example:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    char mem[sizeof(int)];
    int* iptr2 = new (mem) int;

    delete iptr2;       // Whoops, segmentation fault!

    return 0;
}
```

Here, the memory for `int` wasn't allocated using `new`, hence the segfault for `delete`.

What exactly does `delete` not like here? Is there some additional structure hidden when an object is initialized with `new`, that `delete` looks for?

**EDIT:**
I'll take out of comments several responses which helped me to understand the situation better:

1. As @463035818_is_not_a_number and @HolyBlackCat pointed out, `mem` was allocated on the stack, while `delete` tries to free memory on the heap. It's a pretty clear cut error and should lead to a segfault on most architectures.
2. If `mem` was allocated on the heap without an appropriate `new`:

The only way to do it I know would be, say, to allocate an `int*` on a heap, then `reinterpret_cast` it to an array of chars and give `delete` a char pointer. On a couple of architectures I tried this on, it actually works, but leads to a memory leak. In general, the C++ standard makes no guarantees in this case, because doing so would make binding assumption on the underlying architecture.

Comment: "Here the memory for int wasn't allocated using new, hence the segfault for delete." there isnt much more to it than that. `new (mem) int;` is placement new, which is different

Comment: Only `delete` what you `new`, and `delete[]` what you `new[]`. Placement new is not included in that.

Comment: Its explained in the article. Did you read it? "Calling placement new directly skips the first step of object allocation. We don't ask for memory from the OS. Rather, we tell it where there's memory to construct the object in [3]. The following code sample should clarify this:" nothing is being allocated, so why would you want to `delete` it?

Comment: I get it as a rule, but why does it work this way? After all we're just deallocating 4 bytes of memory

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Definitely read the article - I don't see the explanation beyond the comment above

Comment: the memory is not dynamically allocated. `mem` is an array on the stack. You cannot `delete` it

Comment: If you try to call `delete` on something that wasn't allocated with `new` then you invoke *undefined behavior* - that is the rule defined by the language

Comment: please do not edit answers into the question. SO is not a discussion forum. If you want to summarize answers/comments you can post an answer.

Answer (score 4):

`delete` deletes objects from the heap. Your object is on the stack, not on the heap.

`new` (`new T`, not the placement-new you used) does two things: allocates heap memory (similar to `malloc()`), then performs initialization (for classes, calls a constructor).

Placement-`new` (what you used) performs initialization in *existing* memory, it doesn't allocate its own.

And `delete` does two things: calls the destructor (for class types), then frees the heap memory (similar to `free()`).

Since your object is not on the heap, `delete` can't delete its memory.

There's no "placement-`delete`" that only calls the destructor. Instead, we have manual destructor calls:

If you had a class type, you'd do `iptr2->MyClass::~MyClass();` to call the destructor. And freeing the memory is then unnecessary since stack memory is automatically deallocated when leaving the current scope.

---

Also note that you forgot `alignas(int)` on your char array.

Comment: Thanks - agree on the stack/heap inconsistency. Do you know what would happen on a typical architecture if it was a pointer to a memory block allocated on a heap? (see my EDIT to the original question)

Comment: @LazyCat You mean `new`, then delete a `reinterpret_cast`ed pointer? Practically, that would call the wrong destructor (if any), because `delete` knows what destructor to call from the pointer type. (This smells of crashes and leaks if the destructor cleans up memory or does something useful.) And formally, this is UB. There might be other issues, when inheritance and virtual destructors are involved.

Answer (score 2):

> What exactly delete doesn't like here?

The fact that it was called for a pointer that did not come from a real `new`.

> Is there some additional structure hidden when an object is initialized
> with new, that it looks for?

That is a near certainty *for your C++ implementation*, but it's completely immaterial. This is undefined behavior, full stop. `delete` is defined only for pointers to objects that were created with a non-placement `new` operator. Otherwise this is undefined behavior. This is an important distinction. The "your C++ implementation" part is relevant. It's certainly possible that a different C++ compiler or operating system will produce code that doesn't crash, and does nothing at all. Or it may draw a funny face on your monitor screen. Or play a tune that you hate, on your speakers. This is what "undefined behavior" means. And in this case, "undefined behavior" means a crash, in your case.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe, it's not clear from my post, but I'm looking for the logic behind this rule. "It is the case, because it's the rule" is not entirely satisfactory even though that's what I tell my kids from time to time..

Comment: @LazyCat actually this answer explains the logic quite well. The logic is that `delete iptr2` is undefined. The expression has no meaning, hence anything can happen. And what actually happens is up to the implementation.

Comment: @LazyCat • To which rule are you looking for the logic behind?

Comment: @Eljay To why you cannot deallocate memory on a heap with delete if it wasn't allocated with new.

Comment: Because this is a part of the C++ standard. It is what it is. This is what the C++ standard specifies.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik OK, how does it know that a given pointer to a memory block on a heap was constructed with `new`?

Comment: On all the platforms I've worked on, **automatic memory** is allocated from the **stack**.  **Dynamic memory** is allocated on the **heap**.

Comment: It doesn't, @LazyCat, it expects the programmer who wrote the C++ program to know that, expects that it is, and proceeds with its internal logic, accordingly.

Comment: It knows that a given pointer to a memory block on a heap was constructed with `new` (and not `new[]` or placement `new`) because the programmer returns that memory using `delete`.  It's the programmers responsibility.  But if the programmer lies to the compiler, the compiler might do something unexpected.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik If it doesn't then it can't apply your rule. And then the only possible answer to my question seems to be: (1) If I try to `delete` a memory block from the stack, it will complain that it's not a heap memory (which it can differentiate). (2) If I try to `delete` a memory block on a heap, it will try to delete it, but the result may depend on the architecture, because it may not know the size of the block to be deleted

Comment: Unfortunately, @LazyCat, C++ does not work this way. There is no requirement that compiled C++ code must detect every instance of undefined behavior, and produce a happy little error message explaining everything. It is the code's responsibility to avoid undefined behavior, otherwise there are no defined results, by definition. This is what makes C++ the most complicated and hardest to learn general purpose programming language in use today. There is no other answer here: this crash is due to undefined behavior. The actual, mechanical, underlying reason for the crash is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can only `delete` what has been allocated via `new`.

As explained in the article, placement new, skips the allocation:

> Calling placement new directly skips the first step of object allocation. We don't ask for memory from the OS. Rather, we tell it where there's memory to construct the object in [3]. The following code sample should clarify this:

You cannot `delete` `mem` because it has not been allocated via `new`. `mem` has automatic storage duration and gets freed when `main` returns.

Placement new in your code creates an `int` in already allocated memory. If `int` had a destructor you would need to call the destructor (but not deallcoate the memory). Placing the `int` in the memory of `mem` does not change the fact that `mem` is allocated on the stack.

Actually the placement new in the code is not that relevant for the issue in the code. Also this code

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    char mem[sizeof(int)];   
    delete iptr2;       // Whoops, Undefined    
    return 0;
}
```

Has undefined behavior just as your code has.

Comment: Thanks. heap/stack allocation is a good point. What if I allocate 4 chars on a heap and reinterpret_cast them to an int pointer? Is there a good reason why it still shouldn't be valid?

Comment: @LazyCat if you reinterpret some memory address to a pointer to `int` then there is no `int`. C++ has rules about when and how objects come into existance. They are rather involved and I dont understand all details myself. But with certainty: In your code an `int` is created. If you just reinterpret pointer to `mem` to pointer to `int` and then try to use that `int` you get undefined behavior, because there is no `int`

Comment: @LazyCat consider that with completely "normal" use of `new` and `delete` already the implementation has to keep track of the addresses and what has been allocated somehow. `int* x = new int[5]; delete[] x;` this only works because somehow the implementation knows that `x` poitns to an array of size `5`. The implementation makes sure that such stuff works. In your code you broke the contract, hence the assumptions the implemenation makes in order to get the right code to work do not hold, and wrong things will happen, thats undefined behavior

Comment: @LazyCat `delete x;` would be undefined behavior as well. Not because there is a rule that says "If you use `new int [5];` and then use use `delete` instead of `delete []` then xy happens", but because there is a rule that says  that you need to use `delete []` for what has been allocated via `new []` and you broke that rule

Comment: @LazyCat actually "rule" is the wrong word. "definition" is much better. The standard defines what happens when you `delete` an object that has been allocated via `new`. It does not define what happens when you `delete` an object that has not been allocated via `new`.

Comment: @LazyCat • Doing something in C++ that is not defined by the language standard is what **undefined behavior** means.  In the context of undefined behavior, any observed behavior (crashing, seeming to work, emailing your browser history to your grandmother) is all acceptable behavior.  Is there a reason C++ allows this?  Yes, for performance.  Is it a good rule? That's subjective; if you don't like it there are many other languages to choose from.

Comment: @LazyCat and something I compeltely missed to mention... the standard never mentions a crash. There is nothing that says "if you do this then your program will crash". A segfault is only one possible symptom of UB

Answer (score 1):

There are several flavours of `new` and `delete`.

The (non-placement) `new` operator allocates memory by calling the `operator new()` function. The `delete` operator frees memory by calling the `operator delete()` function. They are a pair.

(Confused yet? Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885849/difference-between-new-operator-and-operator-new), or maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962467/why-is-the-new-operator-allowed-to-return-void-to-every-pointer-type/8962536#8962536)).

The `new[]` operator allocates memory by calling the `operator new[]()` function. The `delete[]` operator frees memory by calling the `operator delete[]()` function. They are a different pair.

The placement `new` operator does not allocate memory and does not call any kind of `operator new()`-like function. There is no corresponding `delete` operator or `operator delete()`-like function.

You cannot mix `new` of one flavour with `delete` of a different flavour, it makes no sense and the behaviour is undefined.