# Why should I avoid using malloc in c++?

Tags: c++, malloc, new-operator

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is the difference between new/delete and malloc/free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240212/what-is-the-difference-between-new-delete-and-malloc-free)
>   [In what cases do I use malloc vs new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new)

Why should I avoid using `malloc` in c++?

Comment: duplicate of many, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240212/what-is-the-difference-between-new-delete-and-malloc-free for one.

Comment: Ya, just close this question out. I did a poor job searching for a duplicate question

Comment: Because `malloc` just allocates memory. C++ usually intends on using objects, not raw memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `malloc` does not call the constructor of newly allocated objects.

Consider:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() { /* some non-trivial construction process */ }
    void Bar() { /* does something on Foo's instance variables */ }
};

// Creates an array big enough to hold 42 Foo instances, then calls the
// constructor on each.
Foo* foo = new Foo[42];
foo[0].Bar(); // This will work.

// Creates an array big enough to hold 42 Foo instances, but does not call
// the constructor for each instance.
Foo* foo = (Foo*)malloc(42 * sizeof(Foo));
foo[0].Bar(); // This will not work!
```

Comment: The comment concerning the usage of malloc is incorrect - you've allocated 42 bytes, not necessarily enough space to hold 42 instances of the type. You'd need to do `42 * sizeof(Foo)` to allocate enough space, correctly. But you're correct that the constructors would not be called.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after re-reading it.