# what is the difference between Malloc and new operator to allocate a memory?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between new/delete and malloc/free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240212/what-is-the-difference-between-new-delete-and-malloc-free)

I was confused when I create an object by using new operator in C++. There must be difference between malloc and new operator that would allow me to resize the memory block. If I want to allocate a memory I use malloc but what if I use a new operator?

İsn't it allocate a memory? Can you explain that when shoul I use malloc and when should I use new ?

```
X* ptr = new(1,2) X;

obj = (ObjID *)malloc( sizeof(ObjID) );
```

thanks so much.

Comment: that'is true that I find my answer on there, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In C++ you should always use `new` and pair it with `delete`.

- It calls constructor(s) for the object(s).
- Since it is an operator, it can be overloaded.
- It throws exceptions, but there is an exceptionless version.
- There is a "placement new", which allows you to put your object in already allocated memory.

Answer (score 2):

`new` allocates memory and also calls the class constructor for the type you are allocating.

Answer (score 2):

`new` will not only allocate you memory for objects but will also call the constructor on the objects created.  `malloc` will just allocate you a block of memory of the given size with no guarantee of the contents.

Answer (score 1):

malloc gives you raw memory with garbage bytes left around. New uses malloc internally, too. Use malloc if raw memory is all you need.

Comment: "New uses malloc internally, too". Not true. It *may* use malloc (and often does) but can use some other way to allocate memory. It's implementation dependent.