# Differences between `malloc` and `new`

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between new/delete and malloc/free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240212/what-is-the-difference-between-new-delete-and-malloc-free)

Could someone please revise/edit the below - the differences between malloc and new - and see if everything is correct, or am I missing something or got something wrong?  Thank you,

Both `malloc` and `new` are used for Dynamic Memory Allocation.

`malloc` is a C function, whereas `new` is a C++ operator.

`malloc` requires a special typecasting when it allocates memory dynamically,
whereas `new` does not require any typecasting.

Whenever we use `new` for allocating memory, it also invokes any required constructors, whereas `malloc` doesn't do that.

`malloc` can fail and returns a `NULL` pointer if memory is exhausted, whereas `new` never returns a NULL pointer, but indicates failure by throwing an exception instead.

While using `malloc`, `free` is the C function used to free up the allocated memory.

While using `new`, `delete` is the C++ operator used to free up the allocated memory AND call any required destructors.

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240212/what-is-the-difference-between-new-delete-and-malloc-free

Answer (score 1):

Important things to note and remember:

1. `placement new`
2. `delete[]`
3. `_set_new_handler()` function

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add the following with your differences,

1. malloc" does is allocate memory and return a pointer to it. For whatever reason, the designers of the C language implemented it as a standard library function.
    On the Other hand "new" is to instantiate an object, by allocating memory and calling the appropriate constructors. Seems reasonable to me that this function is far more tied to the language than something that simply allocates storage.
2. new calls constructors, while malloc() does not. In fact primitive data types (char, int, float.. etc) can also be initialized with new.

Answer (score 0):

It looks ok, but you could stress the fact that you should never mix `malloc` with `delete` and `new` with `free`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget `new[]` and `delete[]`, for array allocation and deallocation respectively.