# relation between C++ operators new/delete and malloc/free

Tags: c++, malloc, new-operator, glibc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between new/delete and malloc/free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240212/what-is-the-difference-between-new-delete-and-malloc-free)

Can anyone please tell me the relation between the c++ operators like new/delete etc and the functions in libc i.e malloc/free. Though just tested it positive that a call to new/free actually lands up to malloc and free respectively. So that means libstdc++ inherently requires libc.

Comment: Whether or not `new` and `delete` result in calls to `malloc` or `free` is completely implementation defined, and not behavior you can rely on. On the implementation you tested, that seems to be what happens, but it doesn't have to, and with a different compiler or on a different platform, it may not.