# When is it necessary to make explicit destructor calls?

Tags: c++, scope, destructor

Is there any possible situation where using standard `new`/`delete` isn't enough and we need to explicitly call a destructor, like `pA->~A()`?

I think it's only necessary in some resource management classes, but usually is a bad idea. The destructor is called automatically at the end of scope, so why would I want to explicitly call it myself?

An explanation with an example would be great!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++11 you can have a `union` with types needing a destructor. Since the compiler doesn't track which type is currently active, you'll need to explicitly destroy the current member when replacing the currently active member or when destroying the `union`.

In 9.5 [class.union] paragraph 4 the standard uses the following example code to switch from the current active member `m` to the newly active member `n`:

```
u.m.~M();
new (&u.n) N;
```

Comment: +1 TIL that you can placement-`new` (and manually destruct) `union` members, at least in C++11. I seem to recall that this (and generally using non-POD types in `union`s) is UB in C++03....

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: I don't think it is undefined behavior in C++03: I think in C++03 the compiler is required to create a diagnostic when trying to use a non-POD as a member of a `union`.

Answer (score 6):

Another instance where explicit destructor calls are used is with objects that were manually constructed using placement `new`.

Say you were trying to use a `malloc`/`free`-compatible API (e.g., for interaction with C clients that allow specifying custom C-style allocators):

```
void* buf = malloc(sizeof (MyType));
if (buf) {
    MyType* foo = new (buf) MyType;
    // ...
    foo->~MyType();
    free(buf);
}
```

(Though, in this instance, it's better to just use a `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` with a custom deleter.)

Comment: Do you mean calling `delete`? Can you give an example please?

Comment: @Oleksiy You can only use `delete` for objects allocated using `new`. I've provided an example where the memory underlying an object was allocated using `malloc` instead.

Comment: calling delete foo wouldn't be equivalent to foo->~MyType(); free(buf); ?

Comment: @computer No, `delete` does not ([necessarily](http://stackoverflow.com/a/240308/13)) use `free`, just like `new` doesn't (necessarily) use `malloc`. The C++ system has its own allocator that the default `new` and `delete` use. In any case, this is all beside the point, since my example is supposed to be generalisable to the case where C clients are specifying custom allocators (that use a `malloc`/`free` interface).

Comment: but delete foo frees memory also, so frees buf, where MyType is allocated, isn't it? I mean, if I did delete foo, would this be wrong?

Comment: @computer You cannot use `delete` on objects whose memory was allocated using `malloc`. That is because `malloc` may be using a different area of memory from what `new` uses. `new` is [allowed, but not required](http://stackoverflow.com/a/240308/13), to use `malloc` behind the scenes.

Comment: I know this, but here I can see foo is created with new, right? Yes, this is placement new in fact, and this is the reason why I cannot delete foo?

Comment: @computer Yes, that's the reason. Placement `new` doesn't allocate anything. It just allows you to specify a pointer to construct an object at, which must already point to valid memory.