# dynamically allocating a c++ object without using the new operator

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, new-operator

(C++/Win32)

consider the following call:

```
Object obj = new Object(a,b);
```

other than allocating the virtual memory needed for an instance of an `Object`, what else is going on under the hood up there? does the compiler places an explicit call to the constructor of `Object`?

is there any way to initialize a c++ object dynamically without the use of the keyword `new`?

Comment: Define "dynamic". `{ Object obj{a,b}; }` allocates an object as well, and destroys it, without any usage of `new` or `delete`.

Comment: And you really should explain why you ask! Notice that many standard containers are constructing objects....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to initialize an object in some given memory zone, consider the [placement new](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax) (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new))

BTW, the ordinary `Object* n = new Object(123)` expression is nearly equivalent to (see [operator ::new](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/))

```
 void* p = malloc(sizeof(Object));
 if (!p) throw std::bad_alloc; 
 Object* n = new (p) Object(123); // placement new at p, 
                                  // so invokes the constructor
```

<sup>But the implementation could use some non-`malloc` compatible allocator, so don't mix `new` and `free`!</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `malloc` instead of new, but don't forget to always couple it with `free` and not `delete`.

See also :
[What is the difference between new/delete and malloc/free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240212/what-is-the-difference-between-new-delete-and-malloc-free)

Comment: This does not invoke the constructor.

Comment: ... or the destructor with `free()`