# using malloc and free for object creation and deletion? (Just Experimental)

Tags: c++

Why the ctor and dtor are not getting invoked even though the memory is allocated or freed? What is actually happening here? Please share your thoughts.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class a{
        public:
            int i;
                a() {cout<<"\n a ctor \n";}
                ~a(){cout<<"\n a dtor \n";}
};

main() {
        a *ap = NULL;
        ap = (a*)malloc(sizeof(a));
        ap->i = 11;
        cout<<ap->i<<"\n";
        cout<<ap<<"\n";
        free(ap); //does this actually work? Does this free the memory?
        cout<<ap<<"\n";
        ap = NULL; 
        cout<<ap;
}
```

does the above mean ctor and dtor are not useful or they are just useless?

Comment: At what point would you expect the ctor to be called?  Inside `malloc`?  (That seems unlikely, given that `malloc` is a C function, and has no information on types...)

Comment: The constructor and destructor are not called, because `malloc`&`free` are not aware of constructors/destructors. That's it. Also, stop using `malloc`/`free`. `make_unique` and `make_shared` all the way.

Comment: `does the above mean ctor and dtor are not useful or they are just useless?` No, it just means that `malloc`&`free` are useless and not useful.

Comment: have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240212/what-is-the-difference-between-new-delete-and-malloc-free ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is ok here.
The constructor/destructor are just normal functions inside.
What malloc does: Reserve xy bytes of memory.
What new does: Call malloc (or something like that), then call the constructor.
Malloc shouldn´t call any constructor (and it can´t,
because it doesn´t know which one. It does know only a byte count).

If you want to handle memory stuff manually and then just call the constructor,
see "placement new"

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in `malloc` to trigger calling your descriptor; malloc is not for allocating objects it's for allocating a buffer for general use (and not normally for c++). Since malloc is a C library and knows nothing of C++, it would seem a bit off for it to consider calling a C++ constructor -- especially considering constructors can have arguments and malloc has no way to receive those.

If you have a valid reason to use `malloc` to allocate what will become an object, you are still responsible for ensuring the constructor and destructor get called. You do that with `new` and `delete` but your `new` call is modified to be a "placement new". it's extremely rare that you will have a legitimate use for this in conjunction with malloc, but its use in your example would be:

```
    void *ap_addr = void*)malloc(sizeof(a));
    ap = new(ap_addr)a();
    ap->i = 11;
```

Note that you are now responsible for calling both `delete` (to get the destructor called), *and* `free()` (to release the buffer). Of course, buffer release is optional if you're going to reuse it, for example.

Comment: Wouldn't you call the destructor directly rather than using `delete` in this case?  Since IIRC there isn't a placement delete.

Comment: Actually since there's no guarantee that `new` uses `malloc`, calling `delete` here could be undefined behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

1. It should be `int main`
2. What is the problem of using new>
3. Do not mix new/malloc with delete/free
4. use nullptr not NULL

Comment: This is all true, but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - The question at the end was "sharing thoughts"