# Difference between global non-throwing ::operator new and std::malloc

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, malloc, new-operator

C++ has several functions to acquire dynamic storage, most of which differ in some fundamental way. Several more are usually added by the OS.

Two of these are of special interest due to their portability and similarity: `malloc` and `::operator new`.

Are there any differences (w.r.t. the standard and implementation) between the global `void* operator new(size_t, ::std::nothrow&)` and `void* malloc(size_t)`?

Since there seems to be some confusion what I am talking about, consider the following two calls:

```
void* p = ::std::malloc(10);
void* q = ::operator new(10, ::std::nothrow);
```

The obvious and trivial difference is how to deallocate the memory:

```
::std::free(p);
::operator delete(q);
```

Note: This question is not a duplicate of e.g. [What is the difference between new/delete and malloc/free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240212/what-is-the-difference-between-new-delete-and-malloc-free) since it talks about using the *global* `operator new` that does not actually perform any ctor calls.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The main differences, aside from syntax and `free` vs. `delete`, are

1. you can portably [replace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new#Global_replacements) `::operator new`;
2. `malloc` comes with `realloc`, for which `new` has no equivalent;
3. `new` has the concept of a [`new_handler`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/new_handler), for which there is no `malloc` equivalent.

(Replacing `malloc` opens up a [can of worms](https://web.archive.org/web/20170204072041/https://www.iecc.com/linker/linker09.html). It can be done, but not portably, because it requires knowledge of the linker.)

Comment: @gha.st If nothing else, then the fact that it's `::std::malloc` and you're not allowed to add your own names to `::std` unless explicitly permitted to do so.

Comment: Huh, replacing `::operator new` like that is fairly funky

Comment: Some research shows that C++03 already contains the concept of a new_handler (§18.4.2), it has only been extended for C++11

Comment: @gha.st: you're right, C++11 only introduced `get_new_handler`. Fixed.

Comment: (4) `malloc` reports failure as a nullpointer result, `operator new` reports failure via exception, (5) `malloc` is called directly by user code, `operator new` is ordinarily called indirectly via a transaction-like `new` expression that couples allocation and initialization.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The question is about the non-throwing `new`.

Comment: The default alignments of the two are also different. `::operator new` will align the allocated memory to `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__`, while `std::malloc` will align to `alignof(std::max_align_t)`.

Answer (score 6):

There are two differences I can think of:

1. Which function you must use to deallocate the memory, `operator delete` vs. `free()`.
2. A C++ program can legally provide its own version of `::operator new` and that version is guaranteed to be called by `new` expressions. It's not possible to override `malloc` with your own version.

Comment: As far as I know `malloc` is a weak symbol, which means, you can override it.

Comment: @Zaffy That depends entirely on the implementation (compiler & standard library, also linker in this case). As far as standard, portable C++ is concerned, it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The macroscopic difference I can see without further research is that the throwing variant of the global `::new` operator throws `std::bad_alloc` if the allocation cannot be done, whereas `malloc` returns `NULL`. But I do believe that most of the differences listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/240308/671092) apply to the global `::new` operator, even if the topic is about `new`.

Comment: Have a peek at the version of new which takes a `::std::nothrow&` as its second parameter