# difference between `malloc` vs `::operator new`

Tags: c++

```
Airplane *newBlock = static_cast<Airplane*>(::operator new(BLOCK_SIZE*sizeof(Airplane)));

Airplane *newBlock = static_cast<Airplane*>(malloc(BLOCK_SIZE*sizeof(Airplane)));
```

Question> What is the difference between the above two methods used to allocate new memory space? Which one is better in which cases?

Thank you

Comment: Redundancy is it's own reward.

Comment: I am no asking the difference between 'malloc' and 'new operator'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23271495/difference-between-global-operator-new-and-malloc