# What are the things need to be taken care while dynamic memory allocation?

Tags: c++11, dynamic-memory-allocation

When i use `malloc()` or `new` to allocate memory,it sometimes gives run time errors, how to avoid these errors?

Comment: Maybe his Question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240212/what-is-the-difference-between-new-delete-and-malloc-free

Comment: When you use `malloc` to allocate memory for an object, instead of `new`, this may lead to the strange errors (object is not initialized).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you `malloc()`, you need to `free()`.

What you `new`, you need to `delete`.

What you `new []`, you need to `delete []`.

Any other combination is undefined behaviour.

Besides, `new` and `new []` actually construct object(s) in the allocated memory (which `delete` / `delete[]` call the destructor(s) of), while `malloc()` / `free()` don't -- they just handle memory, not objects.

That is as much as I can help you, given the (lack of) information given.