# Why don't malloc and ::operator new mix?

Tags: c++

It's well known that `new` (/`delete`) and `malloc`(/`free`) don't mix.
What was the reason to not make them compatible?

I understand that `new` and `delete` have two responsibilities: constructing and destructing in addition to allocating and deallocating so to make the question more accurate: Why aren't the `::operator new` and `::operator delete` functions required to call `::malloc` and `::free` respectively?

Forcing compatibility would at least allow `realloc`ing of `new`ed arrays of primitive (or rellocatable nonprimitive) types, which can carry noninsignificant performance benefits, and it would make things a little simpler for people who absolutely want to `free` `new`ed memory (when destruction isn't required).

So what is the reason to break compatibility with `malloc` here?

Comment: They have different purposes. Have you read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240212/what-is-the-difference-between-new-delete-and-malloc-free)?

Comment: Maybe one reason was to prevent people doing dangerous things like reallocating an array allocated with `new[]`.  Also, calling `free()` on memory allocated with `new` would break the promise that destructors are called.

Comment: Unless `malloc` does the same thing `new` does I don't see how they can be freely mixed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't think the question is a duplicate. And I don't think reallocing new'ed arrays for rellocatable and primitive types would be a bad idea either -- it can offer sometimes significant speedups, and it's perfectly safe it the type is primitive (no dtor needed) or rellocatable (self contained and no absolute pointers to its own members).