# SIGSEGV error while declaring array without creating new int[size]

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I tried to write code where i have to return the pointer pointing to the first element of array.

I tried using this:-

```
int *construct(int arr[],int n)
{
  int size=(int)(ceil(log2(n)));
  size=2*pow(2,size)-1;
  int st[size];
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    st[i]=INT_MAX;
  constructUtil(arr,st,0,n-1,0);
  int *pt=&st[0];
  return pt;
}
```

This gave me error.
But when i declared the same array like this:

```
int *st=new int[size];
```

It executed successfully.

What is the difference between these two?

Comment: `new int[size]` is a C++ expression, not C. And if you're programming in C++ you should use `std::vector` instead. And perhaps [get a couple of good books to read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to learn it properly.

Comment: As for the problem it's most likely that you return a pointer to a local variable. The array `st` is local to the `construct` function, its life-time will end when the function return, leaving you with a stray pointer.

Comment: The tag `C` is inappropriate for the code context `new int[size]`. Please remove the tag.

Comment: What is `SIGESV`? Did you mean `SIGSEGV`?

Comment: This is not valid C because of the `new` expression. It's also not valid C++ because of the use of a variable-length array (`size` is not a constant expression). Some C++ compilers support VLAs as an extension, but the code is not portable. Incidentally, the problem is that you're returning the address of a local object, but that won't cause problems until the caller uses that address -- and you haven't shown us the calling code. For future reference, please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can´t return a pointer to a local array in C. You have to use `malloc` to allocate the memory and generate a pointer to a memory region for your array. Now you can return the pointer and the memory stays valid:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* construct(int n);

int main()
{
    int* ArrayPointer = construct(100);
    printf("Address: %p", ArrayPointer);

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\n\r", ArrayPointer[i]);
    }

    free(ArrayPointer);
    return 0;
}

int* construct(int n)
{
    int* array = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        array[i] = i;
    }

    return array;
}
```

The instruction `new` does something similar to the `malloc` function (not exactly the same). The key operation of `new` is to ask the OS for some free memory for dynamic allocation (like `malloc` but from another memory pool). See the difference between `malloc` and `new` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240212/what-is-the-difference-between-new-delete-and-malloc-free). Another option (without dynamic memory) is to declare a static array with a fixed size. So the compiler will reserve the memory and you can pass the address of this array to your function