# c arrays: setting size dynamically?

Tags: c, arrays

I am new to C programming. I am trying to set the size of the array using a variable but I am getting an error: **Storage size of 'array' isn't constant** !!

```
01 int bound = bound*4;

02 static GLubyte vertsArray[bound];
```

I have noticed that when I replace *bounds* (within the brackets on line 02) with the number say '20', the program would run with no problems. But I am trying to set the size of the array dynamically ...

Any ideas why I am getting this error ?
thanks much,

Answer (score 11):

You are getting this error because, as the compiler told you, your array size is not constant. In C89/90 version of C language array size has to be a constant. You can't "set the size of the array dynamically". If you need a run-time sized array, you have to either allocate it manually with `malloc` or use some non-standard compiler-specific approach (like `alloca` function).

In C99 version of C language support for so called Variable-Length Arrays (VLA) was added. A C99 compiler would accept run-time sized array declaration for an *automatic* array. Yet even in C99 you can't declare a *static* array of run-time size, as you are trying to.

Answer (score 5):

To create an array of a non-constant size (i.e. known at compile time), you need to dynamically allocate space for it using `malloc()` (and correspondingly deallocate it using `free()` when it is no longer required).

As others have noted, the ability to declare dynamic arrays is available in C99 compliant compilers.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is possible in C99; however, with earlier versions of C, you are stuck calling functions to dynamically allocate memory, e.g. `alloca(3)` or `malloc(3)`.

Answer (score -3):

use either of these

```
GLubyte* vertsArray = (GLubyte*) malloc(sizeof(GLubyte) * bound);

GLubyte* vertsArray = new GLubyte[bound];
```

remember to free the memory when you don't need the object anymore

```
delete [] vertsArray;

free((void*)vertsArray;
```

Despite what they say in the comments I still say that you should prefer *new* instead of *malloc* if you are not 100% forced to use C. See this [link for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new/184540#184540)

Comment: Wrong language - this is a C question. :)

Comment: I though the malloc and free approach were for C, and for that reason I said prefer the usage of new/delete only if supported...

Comment: If your compiler supports `new` / `delete`, it is a C++ compiler, not a C compiler. And you really shouldn't be using a C++ compiler to compile C code for any number of reasons. You shouldn't encourage someone using C to use C++ "if their compiler supports it."