# Operators vs Functions in C/C++

Tags: c++

Someone recently asked me the difference between a C++ standard operator (e.g. new,delete,sizeof) and function (e.g. tan,free, malloc). By "standard" I mean those provided by default by the compiler suite, and *not user defined*.  Below were the answers I gave, though neither  seemed satisfactory.

(1) An operator doesn't need any headers to be included to use it : E.g. you can have a call to new without including any headers. However, a function (say free() ) does need headers included, compulsorily.

(2) An operator is defined as such (ie as a class operator) somewhere in the standard headers. A function isn't.

Can you critique these answers and give me a better idea of the difference?

Comment: is "delete" used in both sets intentionally?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new

Comment: operators are functions, too, even if they have fancy syntax and some overloads are predefined in the language. I guess that what you want to ask is "the difference between c++ defined keywords and c++ functions"

Comment: @paercebal: You could say that (some) operators can be _implemented_ by writing functions which follow a special naming scheme, but I wouldn't say "operators are functions". The infix operator `+` is just that: an infix operator. It might be _implemented_ by the function `operator+()` - or it might not (as in `42+1`).

Comment: @sbi : I guess it's less the implementation than the semantic idea that is important. There is not clear boundary between operator and function. But there is between a reserved keywords/symbols (like `new` and `+` and identifiers) : The reserved keywords/symbols are already used/known by the compiler, whereas the identifiers are declared/defined (possibly using reserved keywords/symbols), usually in headers (standards or not).

Comment: @paercebal: We probably just have to agree to disagree then.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Operators are ***keywords*** with a fixed syntax. Those which can be overloaded might vary a bit in syntax, but that's within the boundaries. The `new` operator is still spelled `new`, even when overloaded and the syntax of invoking it is always the same.

Function names are ***identifiers***, which can be almost arbitrary. There's no syntactic reason you couldn't do away with `malloc()` and use

```
bool my_fancy_alloc(void*& memory, unsigned char size, bool zero_it);
```

instead. (Mark: There *are* other reasons, though. Like your fellow-workers' sanity.)

Comment: +1. I guess the question is wrong at the start (operators vs. functions?), but your answer highlighting the keywords and identifiers answers it all.

Answer (score 7):

An **operator** is compiled to a sequence of instructions by the compiler.

When the code calls a **function**, it has to jump to a separate piece of code

Answer (score 4):

(1) isn't strictly true.  `typeid` is an operator, but its use requires that you include `<typeinfo>`.

My answer would simply be that operators are defined as such.  `::` doesn't necessarily need to be considered an operator, for instance, but the standard says it is, and so it is.

If you're looking for a more verbose answer, I would go on to mention that operators mostly do not *look* like functions.  And those that do [`sizeof` and `typeid`] don't act as functions; their operands are not evaluated at runtime.

Comment: Thanks. But what happens to pure C operators (such as +)? They can't be class operators, but they're operators because the C standard says so?

Comment: @user: I don't understand what you're asking.  `operator +` can be overloaded for classes.

Answer (score 2):

Operators have special syntax, e.g. you can use `new` (or `+`) without putting arguments in brackets after the operator name.

Answer (score 2):

An operator and function are conceptually same.
Both of them take some values as input and return some as output.
They only difference is there syntax.

Answer (score 0):

to my understanding function name is a representation of goto operator, after jumping to a specific code location application can perform one to many unit of work, on the other hand an operator perform an actual unit of work.