# If is a function or an operator in Python

Tags: python

If is a function or an operator in Python. Just I am curious about it. In my opinion, it is a function because it gives output and accomplishes commands. I know that it is statement.

Comment: is your question about [`if`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#if-expr) or about [`is`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is)? neither of them are functions...

Comment: I am asking about If

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2955829/8704792 It refers to C++ but seems to be relevant nonetheless

Comment: It is an element of the conditional statement or ternary operator. Per se it's just a keyword. It's certainly not a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As seen in the [Operator Precedence table](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=condition#operator-precedence), inline if-else (`a if cond else b`) is an operator.

The `if` starting a conditional block is, however, neither an operator nor a function because it is a statement, as described in [Chapter 3 of the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#if).

Answer (score 2):

In python, `if` is a **statement** used for conditional execution. It's not considered a function nor an operator.

I don't think you 'll find a better answer than the python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#if).

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement is not a function, as evidenced by this [list of built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html). It is also not an [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html?#operators), about which you can find information [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp).

It is in fact a [compound statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#if).

Answer (score -1):

Considered if is built-in construction in the core of the language I think it can be considered less of a function but more an operator. If can be described as a set of instructions but at the high level (such as python) it's operator.

Comment: Technically the Python language defines it as a [statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#if), not an [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=operator#operators).