# Using malloc Versus new

Tags: c++, memory, pointers, malloc, new-operator

I've been using `pointer = new type[size]` for a while now and just recently discovered `malloc`.

Is there a technical difference between `malloc` and `new`?  If so, what are the advantages to using one over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`malloc` is a function call, new in this case an expression.

The difference is; `new` will allocate memory and construct all the elements of that array with the default constructor. `malloc` just gives back a chunk of uninitialized memory.

Further still, `::operator new` will throw `std::bad_alloc` or a new handler if one was registered.

The standard library defines a new that accepts a further parameter `nothrow` which returns a 0 pointer if the allocation fails.

```
int *x = new(std::nothrow) int[20]; // include <new>, return 0 on failure
```

Comment: You said what I was about to, but both better and more quickly. I was just in the process of looking one thing up though: is my memory correct that in obsolete versions of the C standard, free(NULL) has undefined effect, whereas delete[] NULL has always explicitly been safe? I'm not immediately able to find any evidence for that so am starting to wonder whether it's a misconception on my part.

Comment: Tommy, IIRC free(0) is defined. I don't know of ancient versions of C though ;)

Comment: Without having the actual specs to hand, Googling suggests that it's in C99 and probably C89, so I don't suppose it matters other than to, ummm, nullify any potential argument that delete[] is 'safer' than free... in a new/malloc discussion it might be worth pointing out the distinction between delete and delete[] though? Just as a technical difference between the two methods of memory allocation.

Comment: Agreed, but that is way more than the scope of the original question, isn't it?

Comment: So in other words, if I use `pointer = new int[20]` I can expect the integers to all be zero, but if I decide to use `malloc` the values might be garbage?

Comment: Maxpm: yes. This is why, when performance is critical one uses `::operator new()` (if not even some more advanced allocator).

Answer (score 2):

You can find FAQ with your question [here](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/heap.html#fqa-16.4)

And another good answer:
[In what cases do I use malloc vs new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new/184540#184540)