# new vs. new (featuring malloc!)

Tags: c++, memory, malloc, new-operator

In C++, it's standard to always use `new` over `malloc()`.  However, in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459358/new-vs-malloc-when-overloading-new), the most portable way of overloading the `new` operator while avoiding platform specific code is to place a call to `malloc()` within it to do the actual allocation.

When overloaded, constructors are called and type-safety is kept.  In addition, you can monitor and control how memory is allocated.

My question, when used in this capacity, are there still any downsides to using `malloc()` within C++?

Comment: @David - The question is, is there any reason I shouldn't use malloc() in C++.

Comment: The use of malloc in your example is to *implement `new`*. Once you have done that (but first consider if you really need to do that, as that's not very common), you just use `new`. `malloc()` doesn't gain any benefits from that.

Comment: @R. Martinho - My goal is to monitor memory use.  Since I use libraries that use STL containers, it's either overload `new`, or change the default allocator inside STL.  I'm picking the lesser evil I think.

Comment: So you will be only using `malloc` inside new, right?

Comment: @R. Martinho - That's correct, and the only place I'd use free is within the overloaded delete and delete[]

Comment: Ok, I guess I misunderstood your question then. Sorry for the hassle :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The biggest downside I can think off is you can't explicitly call `delete` or `delete []` on a pointer that has been allocated using `malloc()` without invoking undefined behavior.  If you are going to go the highly un-recommended path and use `malloc()` to allocate memory explicitly for C++ objects, then you are still going to have to call `placement new` in order to properly call a constructor to initialize the memory location allocated by `malloc()`. Without an `operator new` wrapper on `malloc()`, you'll also have to test to make sure you do not get a `NULL` return value, and create some code to handle cases where you do without the benefit of throwing an exception. It's also very dangerous, and can incur a number of undefined behaviors, if you simply tried to use C-library functions like `memcpy()` to copy C++ objects into heap memory allocated with `malloc()`.

Furthermore, because you utilized `placement new` for your object construction, you are going to have to explicitly call the destructuors for your dynamically allocated objects, and then explicitly call `free()` on the pointers.  This again can cause all sorts of problems if it's not handled correctly, especially if you wanted to work with polymorphic types and virtual base-classes.

If you are going to work with just `malloc()` and `free()`, a nice rule of thumb to avoid undefined behavior pitfalls is to keep the objects you allocate and deallocate with `malloc()` and `free()` to POD-types.  That means non-polymorphic structs or classes with no user-defined constructors, destructors, copy-constructors, assignment operators, private/protected non-static data-members, or base-classes, and all the non-static data-members of the struct/class are POD-types themselves.  Since POD-types are basically C-style structs (but with the added ability to define non-static methods and a `this` pointer), you can safely do C-style memory management with them.

Comment: I would be overloading `delete` to use free().  I assumed the keyword of delete would call the destructor before passing control over to my overloaded function where I would free the memory.  Is that incorrect?

Comment: I believe that would only work if the memory allocated and passed to `placement new` came from a call to `malloc()`.  Otherwise calling `free()` on a memory location that was not allocated via `malloc()` is undefined behavior.  Someone please correct me if I'm wrong ...

Comment: This answer seems to have very little to do with use of `malloc` when overloading `operator new`. When overloading `operator new` your job is to allocate a chunk of memory with requested size and return a `void*` to it. `malloc` is fine for that. - The magic of object creation is done automatically if you use the `new` keyword (as opposed to explicitly calling the overloaded `operator new` function.

Answer (score 7):

If you wish to override `new` and `delete` then you pretty much have to use `malloc` and `free`. That's how it is meant to be done. Do not be afraid.

The downsides of using `malloc()` outside of the implementation of `new()` remain.

Comment: Okay, that's what I was wondering.  I was worried I might be doing something wrong otherwise, based on what I read about malloc and C++

Answer (score 3):

You stated it yourself... the downside to using `malloc`/`free` directly in C++ code is that constructors and destructors will not be run; using `new`/`delete` ensures that constructors and destructors are run. However, there is nothing wrong with indirectly using malloc via the new/delete operators.

Comment: Thanks!  I understand the downsides outside the operators, just wanted to make sure the 'never use malloc/free in C++' axiom was one that had an exception here