# C++ standard library and Boehm garbage collector

Tags: c++, linux, garbage-collection, g++

I want to develop a multi-threaded C++ application (where eventually most of the C++ code would become generated by the application itself, which could be viewed as a high-level domain specific language) on Linux/AMD64/Debian with GCC 4.6 (and probably latest C++11 standard).

I really want to use [Boehm's conservative garbage collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) for all my heap allocations, because I want to allocate with `new(GC)` and never bother about `delete`. I am assuming that Boehm's GC is working well enough.

The main motivation for using C++ (instead of C) is all the algorithms and collections `std::map` ... `std::vector` provided by the C++ standard library.

Boehm's GC provide a `gc_allocator<T>` template (in its file gc/gc_allocator.h).

Should I redefine `operator ::new` as Boehm's one?

Or should I use all the collection templates with an explicit allocator template argument set to some `gc_allocator`? I don't understand exactly the role of the second template argument (the allocator) to [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/)? Is it used to allocate the vector internal data, or to allocate each individual element?

And what about `std::string`-s? How to make their data GC-allocated? Should I have my own string, using `basic_string` template with `gc_allocator`? Is there some way to get the internal array-s of char allocated with `GC_malloc_atomic` not `GC_malloc` ?

Or do you advise not using Boehm GC with an application compiled by g++ ?

Regards.

Comment: It all depends on how familiar with and good at C++ you are. Can you write a decent C++ program without the use of `delete`, and do you realize that `new` should only be said in very, very special circumstances, and that pointers should not be needed for the most part? If you understand all this and conclude that you require a garbage collector, then by all means go ahead. On the other hand if you don't, you might discover that idiomatic, modern C++ is pretty good at user-friendly, deterministic memory management.

Comment: I do know garbage collection quite well, and I believe it is important. The application might become a translator (from some high-level language) to generated C++. And I am not so familiar with C++ to be able to write code without pointers. I am easy with generation of C code, since this is one of the main feature of my GCC MELT work.

Comment: Hehe -- I may be out of line here, but it seems to me that if you *do* know garbage collection but *don't* know C++ very well, then this is a classic "I have a hammer" situation... Why not post a typical snippet of code, and we can see how to do it the C++ way?

Comment: The typical code would be like GCC MELT. It has a million line of generated C. (In other words, the typical code would be generated C++).

Comment: I've never heard of MELT. But if it is something written in or for pure C, then the need for a garbage collector there would be much larger, since C doesn't offer any of the RAII tools that C++ does. So it's understandable that a project in C would be able to take advantage of a GC. But if you want to write genuine, modern C++, that's an entirely different battlefield.

Comment: MELT (http://gcc-melt.org/) is a Lispy high-level domain specific language to extend GCC, and translated to C. It is bootstrapped, MELT translator is coded in MELT. Look into http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/branches/melt-branch/gcc/melt/ for some example of MELT source code, and into http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/branches/melt-branch/gcc/melt/generated/ for example of their translated C equivalent. And I don't want to code a lot in C++, I want to have the C++ generated (my interest is in experimenting DSL-s translated to C or C++).

Comment: I see. That's different from your initial claim, "I want to develop a multi-threaded C++ application", though! Now it sounds like you're mainly interested in C programming...? I cannot speak to that, but I imagine that BGC is a good choice for that.

Comment: No, I am interested in generating C or C++ code from some higher level domain specific language. But I am considering generating C++ ...

Comment: Hm. You really have to pick one. They're different languages. When you generate C++ code and do it right, I'd say you don't need a garbage collector, and it's on *you* to prove why you *would* need one. (Your compiler may well use one, but I'm talking about the resulting code now.)

Comment: Because I am not able to do a fully compile-time garbage collector.

Comment: The comments above are interesting, but they don't answer the (sub) question about the role of the allocator template argument in STL collections.

Comment: Frankly, I think there are too many questions. It's best to be focused and specific. To be brutally honest, if you're not happily at home with C++ allocator mechanics, it's probably premature for you to design a C++ code generation tool, and you should have a thorough grasp of the language you're translating into before approaching such a venture. That's just my personal impression, and I do wish you best of luck and courage for this -- I just think that learning more C++ for a while would be a win-win-win for everyone.

Comment: Simply put, there's no reason at all to use `new` directly, and *never* a reason to `delete` anything. Judging by your post, I am left with the distinct impression that you have absolutely no idea how to write C++ code at all, nor use the constructs provided as Standard, and are using GC simply because it's the paradigm you're used to.

Comment: Show me an example of an interpreter coded in C++ for a high-order language (with recursive lambda & letrec, i.e. a micro Scheme) without any GC.

Comment: I don't understand the reasoning why standard library container would need GC allocators, they can manage their own memory just fine. Likewise do smart pointer. In idiomatic, modern C++, there is very rarely a reason to explicitly (de)allocate memory via `new`/`delete`.

Comment: Simply, because one can need GC for its own classes (again, the good example is to code a high-order functional toy language, like a micro Scheme or a toy ML), and unless you implement your own GC which calls the C++ destructors, you cannot use STL containers & allocators). In practice, if I define a garbage collected Value class [hierarchy] containing map-s and vector-s of Value-s pointers, I cannot ensure that they will be destroyed. Again, show me please an example of an interpreter (of a language with recursive anonymous lambda-s & letrec-s) coded in C++ which don't have any kind of GC.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch A few years late, but cpython implements all of that without using garbage collection within the C++ code (it does, of course, implement a garbage collector on the python code).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer partly my own question, the following code

```
// file myvec.cc
#include <gc/gc.h>
#include <gc/gc_cpp.h>
#include <gc/gc_allocator.h>
#include <vector>

class Myvec {
  std::vector<int,gc_allocator<int> > _vec;
public:
  Myvec(size_t sz=0) : _vec(sz) {};
  Myvec(const Myvec& v) : _vec(v._vec) {};
  const Myvec& operator=(const Myvec &rhs) 
    { if (this != &rhs) _vec = rhs._vec; return *this; };
  void resize (size_t sz=0) { _vec.resize(sz); };
  int& operator [] (size_t ix) { return _vec[ix];};
  const int& operator [] (size_t ix) const { return _vec[ix]; };
  ~Myvec () {};
};

extern "C" Myvec* myvec_make(size_t sz=0) { return new(GC) Myvec(sz); }
extern "C" void myvec_resize(Myvec*vec, size_t sz) { vec->resize(sz); }
extern "C" int myvec_get(Myvec*vec, size_t ix) { return (*vec)[ix]; }
extern "C" void myvec_put(Myvec*vec, size_t ix, int v) { (*vec)[ix] = v; }
```

when compiled with `g++ -O3 -Wall -c myvec.cc` produces an object file with

```
 % nm -C myvec.o
                 U GC_free
                 U GC_malloc
                 U GC_malloc_atomic
                 U _Unwind_Resume
0000000000000000 W std::vector<int, gc_allocator<int> >::_M_fill_insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, gc_allocator<int> > >, unsigned long, int const&)
                 U std::__throw_length_error(char const*)
                 U __gxx_personality_v0
                 U memmove
00000000000000b0 T myvec_get
0000000000000000 T myvec_make
00000000000000c0 T myvec_put
00000000000000d0 T myvec_resize
```

So there is no plain malloc or `::operator new` in the generated code.

So by using `gc_allocator` and `new(GC)` I apparently can be sure that plain `::opertor new` or `malloc` is not used without my knowledge, and I don't need to redefine `::operator new`

---

#### addenda (january 2017)

For future reference (thanks to Sergey Zubkov for mentioning it on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Java-has-automatic-garbage-collection-Why-wasnt-similar-feature-added-to-C++-in-revised-versions-of-language/answer/Sergey-Zubkov-1) in a comment), see also [n2670](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2670.htm) and [`<memory>` and garbage collection support](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory#Garbage_collector_support) (like [std::declare_reachable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/gc/declare_reachable), [std::declare_no_pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/gc/declare_no_pointers), [std::pointer_safety](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/gc/pointer_safety) etc...). However, that has not been implemented (except in the trivial but acceptable way of making it a no-op) in current GCC or Clang at least.