# resolving C++ operator new ambiguity (how to force it)?

Tags: c++, syntax, g++, c++11

My code (not yet released, in file `iaca.hh`) is on [pastebin: Basile Iaca C++ new conflict](http://pastebin.com/CEijaKsn)
I'm using GCC 4.6 on Debian/Linux/Sid AMD64 with the C++11 dialect.

```
g++  -std=c++0x -Wall -Wextra -g -O -flto -I/usr/local/include -o iaca.hh.gch iaca.hh 
iaca.hh:631:2: warning: #warning should implement the methods [-Wcpp]
iaca.hh: In static member function 'static IaDictionnaryItem* IaDictionnaryItem::make()':
iaca.hh:964:46: error: request for member 'operator new' is ambiguous
/usr/local/include/gc/gc_cpp.h:304:14: error: candidates are: static void* gc::operator new(size_t, void*)
/usr/local/include/gc/gc_cpp.h:296:14: error:                 static void* gc::operator new(size_t, GCPlacement)
/usr/local/include/gc/gc_cpp.h:293:14: error:                 static void* gc::operator new(size_t)
iaca.hh:675:7: error:                 static void* IaAnyValue::operator new(size_t, IaAnyValue::allocate_new_value_st)
iaca.hh:667:7: error:                 static void* IaAnyValue::operator new(size_t, size_t, IaAnyValue::allocate_new_value_st)
```

I can't figure out what is the right syntax for forcing `operator new`. I want the one from my class `IaAnyValue` to be called in my function `IaDictionnaryItem::make` at the end of my `iaca.hh` file

I've introduced the empty `allocate_new_value` to solve the ambiguity, without success.

I tried without success

```
IaDictionnaryItem* IaDictionnaryItem::make() {
  return new(IaAnyValue::allocate_new_value) IaDictionnaryItem;
}
```

and

```
IaDictionnaryItem* IaDictionnaryItem::make() {
  return IaAnyValue::operator new(IaAnyValue::allocate_new_value) IaDictionnaryItem;
}
```

From what I know, the operator new is always called with sizeof (*this) as implicit first argument, etc.

Some motivations about my question is in [this question about Boehm's GC & C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016945/c-standard-library-and-boehm-garbage-collector). Please, don't tell me I should not use Boehm's GC. I need to use it (otherwise I won't use C++).

What is the right syntax to force the good operator new to be called?

I want the Boehm's GC allocator to be used. It is available thru the `gc_cleanup` class, which is in `class IaItemValue : public IaAnyValue, gc_cleanup` and  also as the `new` in my `class IaAnyValue` (the only super-class of `IaDictionnaryItem`) I agree there is ambiguity, I just don't guess the syntax to force it.

So how should I code my trivial `IaDictionnaryItem::make` at the end of the file to get it compiled successfully?

For readability, I would prefer calling `IaAnyValue::operator new` with `sz=sizeof(*this)` i.e. `sizeof(IaDictionnaryItem)`, `gap=0` and `al=allocate_new_value`. I just can't figure out the syntax to force this particular one to be called (of course, I still want the constructor of `IaDictionnaryItem` to be called inside  `IaDictionnaryItem::make`).

I've tried to force the `gc::operator new(size_t size, GCPlacement gcp)` (the `gc` class is inherited by  `gc_cleanup` from `<gc/gc_cpp.h>`) using

```
IaDictionnaryItem* IaDictionnaryItem::make() {
  return new (UseGC) IaDictionnaryItem;
}
```

My  `make` function is a static function returning a new instance of my object. Remember that I'm using Beohm's GC, and it will eventually release the memory used (and `delete` the object) when no pointers point to it.

But I'm still getting

```
iaca.hh: In static member function 'static IaDictionnaryItem* IaDictionnaryItem::make()':
iaca.hh:962:22: error: request for member 'operator new' is ambiguous
/usr/local/include/gc/gc_cpp.h:304:14: error: candidates are: static void* gc::operator new(size_t, void*)
/usr/local/include/gc/gc_cpp.h:296:14: error:                 static void* gc::operator new(size_t, GCPlacement)
/usr/local/include/gc/gc_cpp.h:293:14: error:                 static void* gc::operator new(size_t)
iaca.hh:675:7: error:                 static void* IaAnyValue::operator new(size_t, IaAnyValue::allocate_new_value_st)
iaca.hh:667:7: error:                 static void* IaAnyValue::operator new(size_t, size_t, IaAnyValue::allocate_new_value_st)
```

Regards.

**EDIT:** Here is simple example of the problem:

```
#include <cstddef>
struct A {};
struct B { void* operator new(std::size_t, A); };

struct C {};
struct D { void* operator new(std::size_t, C); };

struct E : B, D {};

int main()
{
    //I want to use `void* D::operator new(std::size_t, C);` to allocate memory
    //but it will not compile because the call to operator new is ambiguous.
    new(C()) E;
}
```

Comment: I'd go with the compiler on this one. It is ambiguous. Which of the three defined `new` operators do you want to call? `new (size_t, void*)`?

Comment: If you overload the `new` and `delete` operator for your class then those operators will replace the global `new` and `delete` operators and will result in calls to your defined operators for your objects,You will not need to call them explicitly.Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194127/how-should-i-write-iso-c-standard-conformant-custom-new-and-delete-operators) helps

Comment: I agree on the ambiguity (I know well enough that GCC is almost always right; I'm working on GCC myself :-). I just don't know well enough C++ tricks to force it. I've edited my question to explain a bit more.

Comment: I still don't know which of the three you want to call.

Comment: Any of them will do, they all call `GC_MALLOC`. I just can't figure out the syntax to force one particular of them 3... For readability, I would prefer calling `IaAnyValue::operator new` with `sz=sizeof(*this)`, `gap=0` and `al=allocate_new_value` but I think that if you give me one solution I could adapt.

Comment: Consider producing a minimal sample which demonstrates the problem that you are having. The 1000 line file in pastebin is a lot to sift through, and it is not even complete (even though it contains a lot of irrelevant stuff).

Comment: It is complete enough to be compiled as a header file.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: It doesn't even contain a main function (unless one is being generated by macros in some hidden way). I have been looking at it for 10 minutes now, and I haven't even been able to find the relevant part of the code.

Comment: It's not a complete program, just a header, that I compile with the `g++` command given in the question. And the header don't compile.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: What is your `make()` function supposed to do? It seems to allocate memory for no reason and promptly lose the pointer to that allocated memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is a multiple inheritance issue.  Notice that the class `IaItemValue`  inherits from both `IaAnyValue` and `gc_cleanup` (and `IaDictionnaryItem` inherits from `IaItemValue`), both of which provide overloads for `operator new`.  In order to resolve this, you can add the following line to the class definition for `IaDictionnaryItem`:

`using IaAnyValue::operator new;`

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there some syntax to invoke a particular case of `operator new` (with the construction step) by forcing it??

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Yes there is: `IaAnyValue::operator new()`. Unfortunately this is not particularly useful, because there is no way to manually call the constructor for the allocated memory, and calls to `new` will always end up net being able to resolve the overloaded `operator new`s. Also note that the `BaseClass::functionName` syntax is available for things other than `operator new`.

Answer (score 2):

In order to understand your problem, I've dug through your code and can make the following assertions:

- `IaAnyValue::allocate_new_value` is a `struct allocate_new_value_st {}`
- `GCPlacement` is an `enum { NoGC, PointerFreeGC }`

You have three defined `new` operators:

```
void* operator new(size_t);               
void* operator new(size_t, GCPlacement);  
void* operator new(size_t, void*);
```

You need to be specific about what you call.

To call `new(size_t)`:

```
new X;
```

To call `new(size_t, GCPlacement)`:

```
new(NoGC) X;
```

To call `new(size_t, void*)`:

```
allocate_new_value_st Y;
new(&Y) X;
```

Comment: Thanks!! It is almost right, but I don't understand the last answer. I've created the empty `struct allocate_new_value_st` precisely to (artificially) be able to disambiguate. And I tried using `return new (UseGC) IaDictionnaryItem` and I am still getting the error...

Comment: I edited my question to explain what I tried to follow your suggestion. I don't want `new (NoGC)` but `new (UseGC)`