# C++ - overload operator new and provide additional arguments

Tags: c++, memory-management, operator-overloading, placement-new

I know you can overload the operator `new`. When you do, you method gets sent a `size_t` parameter by default. However, is it possible to send the `size_t` parameter - as well as additional user-provided parameters, to the overloaded `new` operator method?

For example

```
int a = 5;
Monkey* monk = new Monkey(a);
```

Because I want to override new operator like this

```
void* Monkey::operator new(size_t size, int a)
{

...

}
```

Thanks

#### EDIT: Here's what I a want to accomplish:

I have a chunk of virtual memory allocated at the start of the app (a memory pool). All objects that inherit my base class will inherit its overloaded new operator. 
The reason I want to sometimes pass an argument in overloaded new is to tell my memory manager if I want to use the memory pool, or if I want to allocate it with malloc.

Comment: While this is possible, I would like to know what the motivating use case is. What do you want to pass as the `int` argument to `new`?

Comment: Why do you want to overload `new`?  What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: That is interesting, how will you deallocate memory for your object?

Comment: @luskan: you can likewise pass an extra argument to `delete` and you would e.g. pass the same memory pool used for `new`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: No, you can't pass an extra argument to `delete`.  Placement versions of `operator delete` are only called when the constructor throws an exception.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Are you sure of that? Boehm's GC have a `void operator delete( void*, GCPlacement)` in its `class gc` inside `<gc/gc_cpp.h>`?  And I also have defined my delete operator with extra arguments.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: And those are called when construction fails.  "If a *new-expression* calls a deallocation function, it passes the value returned from the allocation function call as the first argument of type `void*`. If a placement deallocation function is called, it is passed the same additional arguments as were passed to the placement allocation function, that is, the same arguments as those speciﬁed with the *new-placement* syntax." (section `[expr.new]`).  But there is no placement syntax for the `delete` or `delete[]` operators.

Comment: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#placement-delete

Comment: I was not talking of the placement new provided by standard `<new>` header; I was talking of providing my own `new` and `delete` operators...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: So is that section.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Invoke new with that additional operand, e.g.

```
 Monkey *amonkey = new (1275) Monkey(a);
```

#### addenda

A practical example of passing argument[s] to your `new` operator is given by [Boehm's garbage collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/), which enables you to code

```
 Monkey *acollectedmonkey = new(UseGc) Monkey(a);
```

and then you don't have to bother about `delete`-ing `acollectedmonkey` (assuming its destructor don't do weird things; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8019003/841108)). These are the rare situations where you want to pass an explicit `Allocator` argument to template collections like `std::vector` or `std::map`.

When using memory pools, you often want to have some `MemoryPool` class, and pass instances (or pointers to them) of that class to your `new` <strike>and your `delete`</strike> operations. For readability reasons, I won't recommend referencing memory pools by some obscure integer number.

Comment: I don't get it, why (1275) and then (a) after Moneky? Will the overloaded method look like mine above?

Comment: Because that is how `new` works.  You are wanting to pass a parameter to `new` itself, not to `Monkey`.  So the `(1275)` goes to `new` and the `(a)` goes to the `Monkey` constructor.

Comment: Why? : because it is so defined in the C++ standard (which I don't have access to now).

Comment: And I won't call `operator new` a *method* because it is not a member function (it is `static` since it does not operate on instances).

Comment: Is 1275 just a random number or does it have a meaning?

Comment: A random number. Actually, your question would better have asked to pass e.g. a string -or an enum- to `new`, then I would have given `new("foobar") Monkey(a)` as my example.

Comment: I gave Boehm's GC as a practical & useful example

Comment: I also mentioned rarely provided allocator template arguments.

Comment: I mentioned memory pool classes.

Comment: Actually, you cannot have your own delete ...  
www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#placement-delete –mentioned by Ben Voigt

Comment: I see.. guess I'll have to rethink the design a little, thanks alot for answer!