# Memory usage of loaded shared objects

Tags: c++, linux, memory-management, shared-libraries

I'm working on a Linux-based program that loads many plug-ins in the form of shared objects. What I want to find out is how much memory each shared object, and all its data structures, take at a certain point in time. Is it possible to do that? I can modify both the main program and the plug-in shared objects if needed.

Comment: What kind of program are you working on?

Comment: It's some sort of data analyzer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible dynamically, since it may happen that a shared object `A.so` is dynamically creating at runtime some object data B which is used then destroyed by shared object `C.so`
So you cannot say that some data like B "belongs to" a particular shared object; you may (and should) have *conventions* about that. See [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII), [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29), [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer), ....

<sup>The point is that the question "how many memory is used by a given library or shared object" has no sense. Memory and address-space are global to the process, so shared by the main program and all shared objects, libraries, plugins...!</sup>

You could however use [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) to get information about the entire process. From inside the program, read sequentially `/proc/self/maps` to get the map of its address space. From outside the program, read `/proc/1234/maps` for process of pid 1234.

You might want to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Read more about [memory management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management), [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29), [reference counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting). You could view your issues as related to [resource management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_management_%28computing%29) or [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29). You might want to use [Boehm's conservative garbage collector](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/) (if using standard C++ containers, you'll want to use Boehm `gc_allocator`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8019003/841108)). The point is that liveness of some given data is a *global* property of the program, not of any particular plugin or function. Think about [circular references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference)

Comment: Ah, well, I guess it was worth a try! It seems like I should consider manual accounting or something.

Answer (score 3):

> What I want to find out is how much memory each shared object, and all
>   its data structures, take at a certain point in time. Is it possible
>   to do that?

If the program is running and you have its pid you can examing its memory mappings. For example:

```
% pmap 1234
[...]
00007f8702f6a000    148K r-x-- libtinfo.so.5.9
00007f8702f8f000   2044K ----- libtinfo.so.5.9
00007f870318e000     16K r---- libtinfo.so.5.9
[...]
```

This doesn't tell you much about the data structures et al though.

Comment: Notice that `pmap` is just pretty-printing `/proc/1234/maps`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I know and presumably everyone who uses it knows to strace it to find out what it is reading. Thanks!