# C++ Will this cause a memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I'm trying to understand the use of delete[]. Will the following code have a memory leak?

```
int * getArray( )
{
    int *r = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        r[i] = i;
    return r;
}

int main ()
{
    int *array;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) // main loop
        array = getArray();
    return 0;
}
```

The main loop seems to be allocating memory for 10 arrays, where only the last array has a valid pointer. If this is a memory leak, how do I free the memory storing the previous 9 arrays?

I can also compile using `const int r[10];` in place of `int *r = new int[10];`. Can the use of `const` avoid a memory leak?

Comment: You should get into the habit of using a tool to determine if there is a memory leak like [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: In addition to the answers, read up about RAII to deal with memory management

Comment: Short answer: Yes of course!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each call to `new` must be paired with a call to `delete` to avoid a memory leak (or `new[]` and `delete[]`).

*How to delete the memory* depends on what you're doing but since you don't keep access beyond the for-loop then you could easily delete it within the body of the for-loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    array = getArray();
    /* do  something with 'array' */
    delete[] array;
}
```

Better yet, why not use `std::vector<int>` and avoid directly performing any memory allocation?

**Edit:**
As [@Niall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3747990/niall) mentions in the comments you should also familiarize yourself with `std::unique_ptr` (assuming you're compiler supports it). It uses RAII ([Wikipedia link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjACahUKEwiGzoDnnqTHAhVIbz4KHZ9xAK4&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FResource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization&ei=XJnLVYawMMje-QGf44HwCg&usg=AFQjCNE5aT779vmH9EEox1BZY0dDh-raPQ&sig2=XX38AHVvjpExpGSxy-sPlA&bvm=bv.99804247,d.cWw), [cppreference link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDkQFjAEahUKEwiGzoDnnqTHAhVIbz4KHZ9xAK4&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.cppreference.com%2Fw%2Fcpp%2Flanguage%2Fraii&ei=XJnLVYawMMje-QGf44HwCg&usg=AFQjCNEYFl1PaiY3kTrbGYxPg9CNUH1JSw&sig2=gb08HJfplfsh-QHokX2Y-g&bvm=bv.99804247,d.cWw)) to automatically handle the memory management. For example, `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` which will automatically call `delete[]` once the class goes out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

1. You have a memory leak if you dont call a `delete` for every `new` (or `new[]` and `delete[]`).
2. You need to keep a track of your allocated memory, this loop:

---

```
 for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) // main loop
    array = getArray();
```

will create memory that you cannot recover the address of (for the first 9 arrays) as you have said. There is no way to get the address back so you can properly handle this memory. You need to do something like this:

```
int *array[10]
...
  for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) // main loop
    array[i] = getArray();
```

so that you can then delete all of your arrays correctly:

```
   for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        delete[] array[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

As other answers explained, you have a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) (and using `const` won't help about them).

Several systems (notably Linux) have [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) ported to them. If possible use it (to test at runtime). So compile your C++11 code with `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -g` into a `./myprog` executable, then run `valgrind ./myprog`; it will give you useful diagnostics at runtime.

With recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) you could also pass `-fsanitize=address` to the compiler. Read more about the [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer).

BTW, you should often use [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) in your C++ code, e.g. [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) or [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). Read also about [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), [weak references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference), and the [rule of five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

You might also learn more about [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) techniques ([reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) is a quite limited one, unfriendly for [cyclic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph) graphs, but good enough for [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)s). You could consider using [Boehm's conservative garbage collector](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8019003/841108).

Answer (score 1):

1 - You do have memory leaks. To solve it you can explicitly delete after you're done with each array.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    int *array = getArray();
    // ... Do stuff ...
    delete[];
}
```

Or return a `unique_ptr` for arrays. That way you don't have to delete anything.

```
std::unique_ptr< int[] > getArray( )
{
    std::unique_ptr< int[] > r{ new int[10] };
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        r[i] = i;
    }
    return std::move( r );
}
```

In both cases you can't guess the size of the arrays. You just know you're getting an array of 10 elements.

You could use an `std::array` to manage the memory for you and keep the length of the array visible.

2 - If you use `static` you'll always return the same array and there's no need to delete.

Comment: thanks, this is helpful. Sorry, on the second question I meant to write `const` rather than `static`.