# Things to look out for when writing a std::allocator replacement for STL containers

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl, containers

I have wrote a set of memory management routines for a sandbox 3d rendering engine of mine to start playing around with some concepts. One of the question I have now is if I want to supply my own custom allocator to the STL containers, what are some of the things I have to take note of? I am thinking of replacing the default std::allocator with a pool allocator here. How do I ensure that the STL containers do not over allocate more memory than it is required?

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8019003/841108)