# Malloc doesn't return NULL

Tags: c, memory, malloc, out-of-memory

I just tested `malloc` with a huge memory request and it didn't return `NULL`. I already heard this but the BSD (I'm on a mac) [man-page](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwj9ocacx_TKAhWCChoKHWDeC0cQFggmMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.freebsd.org%2Fcgi%2Fman.cgi%3Fquery%3Dmalloc%26sektion%3D3%26manpath%3DFreeBSD%2B5.0-RELEASE&usg=AFQjCNGgQ7tQxMNgSBTfP3z-U_1rL0zJ4Q&sig2=kJI_eHGQ83-Xylmgulc_dA) says:

> RETURN VALUES 
>        If successful, `calloc()`, `malloc()`, `realloc()`, `reallocf()`, and `valloc()` functions return a pointer to allocated memory.  If
>        there is an error, they return a `NULL` pointer and set errno to `ENOMEM`.

How can I check correctly and reliable, that the returned pointer points to a valid block of requested size?

**EDIT:** I just saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947849/can-i-rely-on-malloc-returning-null?rq=1) post. Same for BSD I guess?

**EDIT 2:** The code:

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t red;
    uint8_t green;
    uint8_t blue;
} RGB_TYPE;

int main() {
    RGB_TYPE *field = malloc(50000 * 50000 * sizeof(RGB_TYPE));

    if (!field)
        return -1;

    ... write to field (SEG_FAULT) ... 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please define HUGE, huge is not a precise qunatity.

Comment: You mean that you don't trust the man ?

Comment: How much memory do you request from `malloc` ?  Post the actual code.  The system may honor your request for more memory than is physically available because it can use a swapfile to implement virtual memory.

Comment: Huge is too fuzzy. Ho much memory are you requiring? Your platform specifications?

Comment: Request to allocate "huge" chunk of memory may have been indeed be granted by the OS

Comment: And also, what are you doing with it? Just `int main(void) {void *pointer = malloc(CONSTANT_VALUE); if (pointer == NULL) printf("Cannot allocate 'Huge' bytes, sorry\n"); return 0;}`? Post the code.

Comment: The functions cannot return `NUILL`, because that is the name of a macro with a _null pointer constant_. And the man-page says they may return a _null pointer_ (mind the case!).

Comment: @iharob Posted the code. Sorry.

Comment: Did you include *stdlib.h*? Are there any compilation warnings?

Comment: @iharob I included *stdlib.h* no compilation warnings with *clang -Weverything -Wextra*

Comment: Sorry, typo slipped in unseen and too late for an edit: It is `NULL`, of course, not `NUILL` in my last comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cause for your problem is somewhat tricky:

`50000*50000*sizeof(RGB_TYPE)` is evaluated as `(size_t)(50000 * 50000) * sizeof(RGB_TYPE)`.  The multiplication associates left to right, so the first multiplication is performed with `int` arithmetics and overflows since `2500000000` is larger than `INT_MAX` on your platform.

Integer overflow invokes undefined behavior, and your platform (`clang`) may generate silly code on this case. It can produce a diagnostic if instructed to (`clang -Wall` or `clang -Weverything`).  In any case, your code crashes because the array does not have the *expected* size.

Change the code to

```
RGB_TYPE *field = malloc(sizeof(RGB_TYPE) * 50000 * 50000);
```

Furthermore, allocating 7.5 GB of memory might be possible on your computer.  It will depend on system configuration, but it is not unrealistic that OS/X will allow that even if you have only 8GB of RAM.

**EDIT:**  On my Mac, your code indeed does not produce a warning with `clang -Weverything`, which is a real nuisance, and tries to allocate `18446744068324649728` bytes.  I get a runtime warning from `malloc`:

```
malloc-test(53877,0x7fff79dbe000) malloc: 
   *** mach_vm_map(size=18446744068324651008) failed (error code=3)
   *** error: can't allocate region
   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

and `malloc` returns `NULL`.  You probably have a different version of the tools and runtime library.

Comment: Thank you really much! This explains a lot, do you know why this question got voted down? What did I do wrong? I didn't post the code at first, that's all?

Comment: Actually 16GB of ram are in here and it's quite possible, but the block was just not valid. Writing turned to a 'segfault', but the change of the operands fixed it.