# Out of memory allocating bytes

Tags: c, memory, arm

I'm trying to build my software on an ARMv7 board with Arch Linux.
Also I build for my software a [PGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profile-guided_optimization) build. The first build compiles without errors, but the second build crashs than I'm using my profile optimized directory for the build.
I got this error message here

```
cc1: out of memory allocating 66574076 bytes after a total of 148316160 bytes
```

Currently I have 2GB RAM.
I've tried to set my swapfile as big as I can (20G) and also my ulimit is unlimit

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 14879
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 14879
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

But it still not compile and I don't know what I can do additionally here to compile my program.

Comment: It might be that the memory is so badly fragmented in the compiler that it doesn't find a block of that size... No matter what size your swap is, the user-space is not that big on ARMv7 but is limited to less than 4G.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala so you mean I can do nothing here at this side?

Comment: Notice that [`malloc` wouldn't even *error* out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947849/can-i-rely-on-malloc-returning-null) if it weren't for the virtual memory

Comment: Try another compiler version, or cross-compile from a 64-bit platform or sth.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala regarding malloc. Will the crash also happen during compile time? And currently I'm using `gcc (GCC) 7.1.1 20170516` and `cmake version 3.8.2`.
Cross compiling worked well, but I want to check the performance improvement on this board. And than I try link my per example against my profiled lib I got a linking error.

Comment: it is a malloc inside cc1 that's failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened to me many times during my builds due to either being,

- Memory is full
- Disk is full

I got the same 'couldn't allocate memory' error in both cases. Just check the memory usage from `top` command to see if all RAM/Swap memory is used.

Also check the disk usage using `df` command. e.g `df -kh` to see your compilation drive is full

When it comes to memory if it's a 32 bit system max memory will be limited to 2^32 ~ 4GB. See [3GB barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3_GB_barrier). Increasing the swap size will not help.

If it's a 64 bit system, memory limit is high, so other possibility may be a permission issue of the file(s)/folder that compiler/linker is trying to access.

Comment: That's why I'm confused, because I have a 20G swap file. The total RAM is used but for the swapfile only 2G are used and than it crashs with the given error above. `df -kh` shows me that I have 24G free space left on my compilation drive.

Comment: I'm not sure if you system is a 32-bit. If that's the case, then your most accessible level of memory could be 2G RAM + 2G Swap. If it's a 64 bit system there won't be such issue. If it's a 64-bit system and still the issue persists, then other possibility is a permission problem in somewhere in the accessed files/folders. I will edit the answer to include this information too.

Comment: It is a 32 Bit system. What I've done now was: Crosscompile this on a 64Bit system and also build my performance test with a toolchain and than copied this on the board and start my measures. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. Hope you will succeed in your work :)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem in `Ubuntu`, except that the problem occurred in compiling a `C++` program with a `MAKEFILE`.

According to my searches, i realized that probably the problem is using of 32-bit system or virtual machine.

I found an easy way to get rid of this problem and it is **delete the existing binary file from the previous compile**.

That worked for me.