# How to tell if malloc failed in swift on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, malloc

How can I detect if malloc fails in swift?

The end goal is to simply allocate the required amount of space, and if ios can not allocate it, report this elegantly to the user (instead of being terminated).

When I try the code below, the pointer is never nil and errno is always 0.

```
let pointer : UnsafeMutableRawPointer? = malloc(fileSize)
print("errno = \(errno)")
if (pointer == nil) {
    print("Malloc failed")
}
```

Comment: The pointer should be `nil` if `malloc` failed. Perhaps it never failed in your tests?

Comment: What platform are you on? On Linux you might be the victim of the "optimistic memory allocation strategy": https://stackoverflow.com/a/7947888/1187415.

Comment: Platform is ios. It's a deliberately large amount of memory, if I try to allocate the same size of memory through other means it fails. Perhaps the fail occurs during some initialisation later?

Comment: What "other means"? Please show the code so that we can compare the different methods.

Comment: This will kill it:           _array = UnsafeMutablePointer<T>.allocate(capacity: _count)            _array.initialize(to: initValue, count: _count)

Comment: Does the allocation fail or the initialization?

Comment: According to https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-12-17-custom-object-allocators-in-objective-c.html#comment-6f3b9bf689eaf4ddec5473dd6dc1dce4, malloc on iOS uses the "optimistic memory allocation strategy" as well. That means that you can get a pointer, but *using* the memory later can crash. Using `calloc()` instead *might* be a solution.

Comment: Thanks Martin, that's exactly what I am observing... which is why I am trying to move away from UnsafeMutableRawPointer's allocate. End goal is to simply allocate the required amount of space, and if it can not be allocated report it elegantly (instead of being terminated by ios). I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: As I recall the last time I went down this road, `calloc` doesn't help either because it fills with 0s, and the memory system is smart enough to leave all-0 pages unmapped. IIRC, even if your allocated block is writable, it doesn't mean that every page will be mappable when you try to write it, and so you could crash then. You can of course fill the memory with non-0 values to force it to be mapped, but that crashes if you're wrong. (So, Rob, how did you fix this? I never did.)

Answer (score 4):

Why are you using `malloc` in Swift, at all?

```
let pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: fileSize)
```

More to the point, under what circumstance does reading a file need you to manually allocate memory like this?  Foundation provides APIs for reading files directly into `Data`.

Comment: Are you sure that `allocate()` doesn't suffer from the same problem? – OP said nothing about reading a file. There can be many reasons to allocate a memory buffer for whatever purposes.

Comment: Because allocate gives no indication of failure either.

Answer (score 1):

LLVM has an optimization which elides unused `malloc` calls.  If your test code never actually needs the allocation, it will never be performed.