# how to find a mac address?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

how can i find in c++, the mac address of the computer that an application is currently running on and then compare that mac address with a certain mac address?

so lets say that certain mac address that we want to compare with is `AB-12-CD-34-EF-56`, how is it possible to find the mac address that the application is running on, then compare that mac address with the `AB-12-CD-34-EF-56` mac address? what is the best and simplest way of doing something like this?

Comment: That depends entirely on the OS you're running on. Given you've tagged this VC++, you'll have to look in the Windows Networking APIs for an appropriate function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [visual 6.0 and finding mac address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365739/visual-6-0-and-finding-mac-address)

Answer (score 3):

On Windows you can use the function [`GetAdaptersAddresses()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get an [`IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure which contains `PhysicalAddress[MAX_ADAPTER_ADDRESS_LENGTH];` (that's the mac adress).

This function will introduce the library `Iphlpapi.lib` and the header file `<iphlpapi.h>` as dependency. A simple example which will print all mac addresses from available adapters:

```
#include <Winsock2.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#pragma comment(lib, "IPHLPAPI.lib")

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  ULONG outBufLen = sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES);
  GetAdaptersAddresses(0, 0, NULL, NULL, &outBufLen);
  std::vector<uint8_t> bytes(outBufLen, 0);
  PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES pCurrAddresses = (IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES *)bytes.data();
  DWORD dwRetVal = GetAdaptersAddresses(0, 0, NULL, pCurrAddresses, &outBufLen);
  if (dwRetVal == NO_ERROR) {
    while (pCurrAddresses != NULL){ 
      for (size_t i = 0; i < (int) pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddressLength; i++) {
        if (i == (pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddressLength - 1))
          std::printf("%.2X\n", (int) pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddress[i]);
        else
          std::printf("%.2X-",(int) pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddress[i]);
      }
      pCurrAddresses = pCurrAddresses->Next;
    }
  }
  std::system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't `new POD()`. Use `malloc` or `HeapAlloc` to stay platform specific... or just a `std::vector<BYTE>`. Avoid `naked new()` as much as possible. And when you use it, use it for proper objects, not POD.

Comment: @CodeAngry Is there any specific reason why I shouldn't use `new` with PODs? The reason why I've used `new` here, is that I've read often on SO, that `malloc` shouldn't be used in C++ at all. i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new

Comment: They say don't use `malloc` for the same reason as don't use `new`. To avoid naked pointers because people have a tendency of forgetting to `free`/`delete` them, especially in code with multiple exits `(returns)`. [Checkout rastertek DX tutorials' code and you'll see.] `std::vector<>` frees the memory on destruct and is good for both POD and objects. The rule of thumb is, unless you really know what you're doing, who owns the object and who accesses it, and are exception-safe... don't use new/malloc. Use `std::containers` or `std::unique_ptr` for your heap object storage needs. - *Hai bafta!*

Comment: @CodeAngry Thank you for your suggestion - I've changed my answer accordingly.