# visual 6.0 and finding mac address

Tags: c++, visual-c++

how can i find in c++, the mac address of the computer that an application is currently running on and then compare that mac address with a certain mac address?

so lets say that certain mac address that we want to compare with is `AB-12-CD-34-EF-56`, how is it possible to find the mac address that the application is running on, then compare that mac address with the `AB-12-CD-34-EF-56` mac address?

i have tried method 3 on http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/network/networkinformation/article.php/c5451/Three-ways-to-get-your-MAC-address.htm

but that dosen't work on visual 6.0, does anyone know how to go about this?

Comment: How did those 3 methods fail in VS6? Compilation error? Runtime errors?

Comment: a bunch of undeclared errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the simplest way but the most reliable way across different version of the Windows OS. You will have to deal with COM.

Query WMI Win32_NetworkAdapter class for MACAddress in question. If MAC address you want to check does not exist, WMI will return empty query.