# Proper allocate memory for PODs

Tags: c++, memory-management

My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24635216/531840) received a comment, regarding the memory allocation in my code. I've used `new[]` and `delete[]`, because I've read before, that you should never `malloc()/free()` in C++ (i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/184540/531840)). The code in question is essentially:

```
ULONG outBufLen = sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES);
GetAdaptersAddresses(0, 0, NULL, NULL, &outBufLen);
PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES pCurrAddresses = (IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES *)new uint8_t[outBufLen];
//...
delete[] pCurrAddresses;
```

The byte-size of memory, which I want to allocate comes from the function `GetAdaptersAddresses()`.
My question is: is there anything wrong with this piece of code? If yes, what would be the proper way in modern C++ to allocate the memory there?

- `malloc()/free()` should be out of question - it's C++ code and I don't see any improvement in using `malloc()` instead of `new[]` here. Right?
- `std::vector<>` seems not right to me - I could write `std::vector<uint8_t> bytes(outBufLen, 0); PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES pCurrAddresses = (IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES *)bytes.data();` but I would have a bad
  feeling, because `std::vector<>::data()` is const).
- Using `std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>` seems also odd - because I have to cast it into a raw pointer anyway.

Any alternatives?

Comment: `std::vector<T>::data()` returns `const T*` only if called on a `const` vector. Otherwise the non-`const` overload is called, which returns `T*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second proposal with `std::vector` is the right one in C++ in most cases. The `data()` is not const (well, it is for const vectors, but in your case it is not). C++ standard ensures that data() returns the pointer to contiguous storage of memory for your PODs.