# Behaviour of malloc with delete in C++

Tags: c++, malloc, delete-operator

```
int *p=(int * )malloc(sizeof(int));

delete p;
```

When we allocate memory using malloc then we should release it using free and when we allocate using new in C++ then we should release it using delete.

But if we allocate memory using malloc and then use delete, then there should be some error. But in the above code there's no error or warning coming in C++.

Also if we reverse and allocate using new and release using free, then also there's no error or warning.

Why is it so?

Comment: Think about constructors and destructors as well.

Comment: There may be no warning about it, but it's definitely an error. (Either way around)

Comment: "*there should be some error*" - says who? The behavior is undefined and the C++ standard makes no comment on what should happen. If you want an error, you may need to use another tool, like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is undefined behaviour, as there's no way to reliably prove that memory behind the pointer was allocated correctly (i.e. by `new` for `delete` or `new[]` for `delete[]`). It's your job to ensure things like that don't happen. It's simple when you use right tools, namely smart pointers. Whenever you say `delete`, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Basically, the C++ standard says that if you allocate with `malloc` and free with `delete`, you can launch a nuclear strike. You wouldn't want that do happen, would you, now? Well, let's be realistic: if you insist on doing it, you'll pay for it months or years later, 3 days before you're due to go for a family vacation, and you'll spend 48h straight figuring out the problem. That's what undefined behavior means in practice. Sleepless nights.

Comment: Whoa whoa whoa, I was with you until your last sentence, and I *like* smart pointers. They're not always an appropriate substitute for new/delete, though (for instance, what if you're writing your own smart pointer class, and you're deploying to an embedded machine with no standard library? What if you're stuck with an old compiler that only provides auto_ptr as a smart pointer?), so it's needlessly limiting to say that using delete is "doing it wrong" (even if it's true that smart pointers are usually a better approach).

Comment: Actually, that still *is* doing it wrong. You shouldn't `delete` directly in your smart pointer, you should instead take a function object (either as template or type erased) and use that to delete the object. The only one single delete required in adding smart pointers is in `std::default_deleter`.

Comment: @KyleStrand Ugh those dumb arguments crop up again and again. If you're writing your own smart pointer class or writing embedded software you're not wondering whether you can mix malloc and delete. Wrong audience. Besides the amount of cases where you'd write your own smart pointer is close to 0, because unique_ptr is generic enough for almost everything (and those other cases are either shared_ptr or deep-cloning value_ptr and all of that is written already anyway). And if you're stuck with 5+ year old compiler then *someone's* doing it wrong for sure (also Boost).

Comment: @CatPlusPlus In that case, it sounds like what you really meant was "when beginners use `delete`, they're doing it wrong"--which is arguably true, but what you said was *much* broader than that. As for 5+ year old compilers, I work for a company that is currently in post-release support for several embedded systems that were programmed using MSVC 2008 (and in one case 2003) targeting XP Embedded and Windows Embedded Standard 2009, and they simply do not have the manpower to port the codebase forward as part of their ongoing maintenance efforts, nor is there any urgent reason to do so.

Answer (score 13):

> then there should be some error

There is. It is just not necessarily apparent.

The C++ standard (and the C standard, on which the C++ standard is modeled) call this kind of error *undefined behavior*. By *undefined* they mean that anything at all may happen. The program may continue normally, it may crash immediately, it may produce a well-defined error message and exit gracefully, it may start exhibiting random errors at some time after the actual undefined behavior event, or [invoke nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

It is your responsibility to watch out and eliminate these errors. Nothing is guaranteed to alert you when they happen.

Comment: I agree that this is UB, but I would like a standard reference to where it says so please :)

Comment: @EmilyL: the C++ standard does not specifically address mixing new and free. It says you may only pass to delete what you've got from new. The C standard says likewise about malloc and free.

Answer (score 6):

Use `free()` not `delete`.

if you `malloc` you then have to call `free` to free memory.

if you `new` you have to call `delete` to free memory.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new) is a link that explains it.