# Does using malloc in method, free in main work?

Tags: c++, malloc

I have the following question:

If I use `malloc` in a method, `return` the pointer to my `main`, and `free` the pointer in my main, do i have successfully freed the memory or not? And is this bad programming style, if i do so?

```
int* mallocTest(int size)
{
    int * array = (int*) malloc(size);
    return array;
}

int main ()
{
    int* pArray = mallocTest(5);
    free (pArray);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: The main purpose of this question is that I want to know, if I freed the memory successfully (if i use the right "combination" of malloc-free/new[]-delete[]) when i split this into the method and the main function!

EDIT2: Changed code and topic, to lead to the intended point of the question

Comment: This is wrong (not just bad style; outright broken). Only ever use `malloc` with `free`, `new` with `delete`, and `new[]` with `delete[]`.

Comment: Malloc with delete is [covered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854210/behaviour-of-malloc-with-delete-in-c).  Don't do it.

Comment: I will change the mistakes, to lead to the "right" point of the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mixing `malloc` freeing it with `delete` is explained in other answers.

I feel you want to know if `malloc` memory allocated in a method, return the pointer to `main`, and `free` the pointer in main will work or not ? Yes it can be done and `free` will clear the memory allocated in other methods provided you have the pointer pointing to that location.

Comment: Yes, the second part was exactly, what i want to know. And in addition I know now, that i made a huge mistake, mixing the malloc with delete.

Comment: @AndroidRookie Ok. In your example you need just the pointer to memory location allocated using `malloc` which can be free'd from other methods.

Answer (score 4):

No. Use `free` to free memory allocated with `malloc`, `delete` for single objects allocations with `new` and `delete []` when using `new` on arrays.

Mixing and matching may appear to work (it's undefined behaviour, and "undefined" included "works fine" and "sort of works fine most of the time, but crashes on thursdays in months starting with M on days that are divisible with 3 or 7 and the operator has shirt with stripes") - and may indeed work on SOME types of systems, but fail on others, depending on exactly how `malloc` and `new` and their respective `free` and `delete` functions are implemented.

It is fine to call a function that returns a pointer to some memory that is later freed with the appropriate call. It is "nicer" if you actually implement a pair of functions, where one allocates and the other destroys the data. This is particularly important if the data-structure allocated isn't trivial (e.g. you have allocations inside the outer allocation).

Also consider what happens if you decide that "Oh, I'd like to use `new int[size];` instead of `malloc(size * sizeof(int));` in the `mallocTest()`". Now every place that calls `mallocTest()` will have to change so that it calls `delete []` instead of `free` that you corrected it to after reading this answer.

[Just spotted that your code is broken, and probably won't compile, certainly won't allocate space: `(int *)malloc[size];` doesn't do what you want it to do, and I'm pretty sure is illegal, as indexing a function is invalid]

And finally, the "best" solution is wrap all allocations in an object, such that the destructor of that object destroys the data allocated within the object. So, for example, use `std::vector<int>` instead of allocating with `malloc`.

Comment: Thanks for that advice, I didn't know that... But this leaves the question open, if I successfully free the memory, if I use the correct "combination" of malloc-free / new[]-delete[], and split them into method and main?

Comment: When you correctly match `free()` to `malloc()`, and `delete[]` to `new[]`, then it's guaranteed to work correctly irregardless of how many function calls pass between allocation and freeing of the memory.

Comment: Thank you a lot for this answer, it was my fault that I didn't double-check my question for this mistake. But as stated in my previous comment, it didn't seemed important for the intention of my question. I fixed the points you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

No - thats undefined bahaviour which means it might look like it works but actually it does not, for `malloc()` you should always use `free()`. Use `delete[]` only for memory allocated with `new[]`.

You can actually check it yourself, `new[]` calls [`void* operator new(size_t)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new%5B%5D/) method which should be somewhere declared in your platform headers. The easiest way is to spy on whay it does with debugger, under VS2005 it calls in the end `HeapAlloc` function.

For deallocation you have [`void operator delete[](void*)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete%5B%5D/) which also must be defined somwhere. On VS2005 it calls `HeapFree`.

I checked what malloc/free calls, and those are also [`HeapAlloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366597%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`HeapFree`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

So in my case it looks like it would work, because `malloc` looks like its implemented in the same way as `new[]`. But the point is that there is no magic here, `new[]` should be paired with `delete[]`, `malloc()` with `free()`, because you never know how those are implemented on given platform.

Answer (score 1):

- When you dynamically allocate memory either using **malloc** or **new**, you
  are "reserving" a part of the heap memory for a particular purpose.
  The memory will remain "reserved" until you return it to the heap
  using **free** or **delete** (depending on what you used for allocation).
- That being said, you can **allocate memory from anywhere in the program**
  and f**ree it from anywhere**. it's important however to be sure and do
  both if you forget to free the allocated memory you get memory leaks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should use `free` with `malloc`, `delete` with `new`, but to me, it is not because of undefinedness, that it may blow a nuclear bomb, invoke nasal demons or whatever. (Or simply, maintenance nightmares) `malloc` and `new` don't do the same thing at all. To simplify what is actually a bit more complicated:

- `malloc`, inherited from C, allocates a chunk of memory. Period.
- `new T` allocates a correctly-sized chunk of memory intended to store an object of type `T` (possibly through `malloc`), and **executes the object's constructor.**

Conversely:

- `delete ptr` **executes the destructor of the object** pointed-to by `ptr` and releases the related chunk of memory.
- `free(ptr)` releases the chunk of memory. Period.

For the universe not to fall apart, every call to a constructor must match a call to the destructor. That's a guarantee of the language. (and one of the greatest strengths of C++)

That's why every call to `malloc` must match a call to `free`, because `free` was made to undo what `malloc` did. And every call to `new` must match a call to a `delete` because `delete` was made to undo what `new`did.